# How different z value is possible where in projection plane z value is constant?

Tags: view, graphics, viewport, surface

We know that any 3D objects can be seen in 2D screen where z-coordinate is constant because projection plane is kept at z_vp (any constant z-coordinate) . But when we use z-buffer algorithm we use different z value in view plane.

My question is if I use different z-value of object in projection plane, it not should be look like 3D image? I mean how images are 2D after using different z-value?

Comment: @Spektre we only see any image/video in 2D on computer screen. But when we use different z-value then then still we see 2D image on screen?

Comment: @Spektre could you insert your comments in answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you ask **how many possible z-values can be stored** that depends on your depth buffer bit width for example 24bit has 2^24 possible depths. Usual bitwidths are `16/24/32` bit. However the depth value is not mapped linearly but logarithmicaly in order to have uniform visual detail on whole range of the viewed frustrum. However in some cases this brings up a lot of problems in which case linear depth buffers are used see:

- [How to correctly linearize depth in OpenGL ES in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)

**The perception of depth on 2D screen is done with:**

1. **lighting/shading**

   so angle/distance between rendered faces and light source and camera matters too (affect color). The easiest lighting model is normal shading see:

   - [Understanding lighting in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004546/2521214)

   On top of this you can add more complex lighting supporting also Light Attenuation (light is dimmer with distance), fog , Scattering ([SSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33581643/2521214) or [atmospheric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) ), Spot lights,Environmental reflections etc...
2. **perspective**

   the scale of objects depends on the distance to camera which allows our vision to estimate relative distance between known sized objects. If objects or camera is moving then this allows relative distance estimation also for unknown size objects.
3. **Hidden Surface Removal**

   This hides objects that are behind other objects. This can be done by Depth sorting (Painter's algorithm) or depth buffering and in some cases just by Back-Face culling. Depth buffering is usually more suitable as its faster and also handles the intersection much better/easier (however some stuff still needs Depth sorting like for example arbitrary transparency).

   Depth buffering also allows to retrieve the 3D information latter which is often used for:

   - [ray picking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214)

If you're interested in more depth explanations see:

- [Mathematically compute a simple graphics pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214)

Comment: explain little "light source and camera matters too (affect color)"

Comment: @Sood added some links to QAs dealing with it...