# How to find the normal vectors for each vertex of a triangle in 3D space?

Tags: matlab, graphics, geometry, normalization

I am coding an assignment in computer graphics where I have to use different light models (ambient, diffusion, specular) for an object consisting of N triangles. Given the coordinates of the three vertices of each triangle in 3-D space, I want to calculate the normal vectors for each vertex.

I have tried the following code using some help I found searching online but I really am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

```
function Normals = findVertNormals(R, F)

     number_of_triangles = length(F);
     number_of_vertices = length(R);
     A = zeros(3,number_of_triangles);
     Normals = zeros(3,number_of_vertices);

     for i = 1:number_of_triangles

         first_vertex = R(:,F(i,1));
         second_vertex = R(:,F(i,2));
         third_vertex = R(:,F(i,3));

         V =  second_vertex - first_vertex ;
         W = third_vertex - first_vertex;

         N = cross(V,W);
         A(:,i) = N ./ norm(N);

     end

     for i = 1:number_of_triangles

         for j = 1:3

             Normals(:,F(i,j)) = Normals(:,F(i,j)) + A(:,i);

         end
     end

     Normals = Normals ./ norm(Normals);

 end
```

where matrix `F` describes which vertices form each triangle and matrix `R` contains the coordinates of vertex in 3-D space.

Comment: Do you mean to calculate the normal vectors for each face and not each vertex?

Comment: No, I mean for each vertex. That is what the assignment asks for.

Comment: There's some ambiguity around calculating a normal for a vertex since it is undefined.  Your approach of averaging the normals of the adjacent faces is a potential way to do it but it doesn't seem very robust to non-uniform triangles.

Comment: A better way might be to do a weighted average with the weights proportional to the angle each face makes with the vertex.

Comment: You might also consider methods based on the edges connected to each vertex rather than the faces connected to each vertex which might be more efficient if that's something you care about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve smooth tangent space normals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766605/how-to-achieve-smooth-tangent-space-normals)