# Recalculate normals of a regular grid surface (C++/OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, vertex-shader, normals

I'm trying to calculate normals of my grid surface. 
The map is 29952px x 19968px and each cell is **128px x 128px**. So I have 36895 vertices.

Grid:
[image: Grid]

My flat map array is sent to shaders with the following structure:

```cpp
float vertices[368950] = {

  //  x     y     z    znoise   xTex  yTex  xNorm yNorm zNorm Type
    16384,16256,-16256,   0,    0.54, 0.45,   0,    0,   1,    1,
    16256,16384,-16384,   0,    0.54, 0.45,   0,    0,   1,    1,
    ......
}
```

I calculate the zNoise with a function

```cpp
float noise(float x, float y){};
```

And it works **(I add it to y and z in the vertex shader)**.

### Method 1

If i calculate normals using **finite-difference method** i obtain a nice result.
Pseudo-Code:

```cpp
  vec3 off = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  float hL = noise(P.xy - off.xz);
  float hR = noise(P.xy + off.xz);
  float hD = noise(P.xy - off.zy);
  float hU = noise(P.xy + off.zy);
  N.x = hL - hR;
  N.y = hD - hU;
  N.z = 2.0;
  N = normalize(N);
```

But, in the case I need to edit the map manually, for example in a Editor context, where you set the zNoise with a tool to create mountains as you want, this method **won't help**.

I get this nice result (seen from minimap) (Normals are quite dark purposely):
[image: nice result]

## Method 2

```
  |    |    |
--6----1----+-
  |\   |\   |      Y
  | \  | \  |      ^
  |  \ |  \ |      |
  |   \|   \|      |
--5----+----2--    +-----> X
  |\   |\   |
  | \  | \  |
  |  \ |  \ |
  |   \|   \|
--+----4----3--
  |    |    |
```

So i'm trying to calculate the normal using the adjacent triangles, but the result is very different (it seems that there's a bug somewhere):

Code.

`getVertex()` is a function that takes x and y returns the vertex info associated to that vertex. `VerticesPos` is an 1d array which contains **the position of each vertex**, in order to be able to get the information from `vertices` (the one that i described above, with 10 values per vertex). i decided to edit the y and the z in the vertex shader to keep untouched the x and y and to use them for **indexing the vertices** through `VerticesPos`. (i hope it's quite clear).

```cpp
glm::vec3 getVertex(int x, int y) {

    int j = VerticesPos[(int)(y/128 * 29952 / 128 + x/128)];

    float zNoise = vertices[j * 10 + 3] * 2;
    float x1 = vertices[j * 10];
    float y1 = vertices[j * 10 + 1] + zNoise;
    float z1 = vertices[j * 10 + 2] + zNoise;

    return glm::vec3(x1, y1, z1);
}
```

`getAdjacentVertices()` is a function that takes a vec2d (x and y coords) and returns the **6 adjacent vertices**, ordered *clockwise*

```cpp
std::array<glm::vec3, 6> getAdjacentVertices(glm::vec2 pos) {
    std::array<glm::vec3, 6> output;
    output = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y + 128), // up
        getVertex(pos.x + 128, pos.y), // right 
        getVertex(pos.x + 128, pos.y - 128), // down-right
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y - 128), // down
        getVertex(pos.x - 128, pos.y), // left
        getVertex(pos.x - 128, pos.y + 128), // up-left

    };
    return output;
}
```

And the last function that does the job:

```cpp
glm::vec3 mapgen::updatedNormals(glm::vec2 pos) {

    bool notBorderLineX = pos.x > 128 && pos.x < 29952 - 128;
    bool notBorderLineY = pos.y > 128 && pos.y < 19968 - 128;

    if (notBorderLineX && notBorderLineY) {

        glm::vec3 a = getVertex(pos.x, pos.y);

        std::array<glm::vec3, 6> adjVertices = getAdjacentVertices(pos);
        glm::vec3 sum(0.f);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int j;
            (i == 0) ? j = 5 : j = i - 1;

            glm::vec3 side1 = adjVertices[i] - a;
            glm::vec3 side2 = adjVertices[j] - a;

            sum += glm::cross(side1, side2);
        }
        return glm::normalize(sum);
    }

    else {
        return glm::vec3(0.3333f);
    }
}
```

I get this [bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twrZH.jpg) (seen from minimap) unfortunately:
[image: bad result]

Note: The buildings are in different positions but the surface **has the same seed** using the two methods.

Could anyone help? :-)

---

### EDIT:

I add more images to help understanding the problem.
Method 1:
[image]

Method 2:
[image: Image2]

Comment: I understand what you try to do and I can follow your code. It seems to be correct to me. Is it possible that the issue is in `getVertex`? `getVertex` seems to read a height associated to a 2 dimensional coordinate and returns a 3D coordinate. Is it possible the the (height) lookup is shifted by 1 per row (line)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I edited the post, adding the `getVertex` function.

Comment: Are you sure about `(int)(y/128 * 29952 / 128 + x/128)`? If the texture has 29952 pixel in a row, then it has to be `(int)(y/128 * 29952 + x/128)`? Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, because 29952 is the map-width, but keep in mind that we have one vertex every 128px, so we have 234 vertices on x-axis and 156 on y-axis.

Comment: Are there 234 tiles or vertices along the y axis?

Comment: @Rabbid76 156. The map is 29952px x 19968px. Now i will try to add more information with some extra-screenshots

Comment: Did not go through your code at all but the last image looks like some of your normals have reversed direction and the render is interpolating between opposing normals creating the wavy pattern (like 2nd or higher degree derivation of surface) not sure how you recomputing assuming by a cross product check if your operand order creates normal on the same side for all nodes of your grid, another option might be wrong summation of neighboring normals see [How to achieve smooth tangent space normals?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930058/2521214) on  regular grid its simple. But I just guess here

Comment: @Spektre in method 2 i'm trying to do your algorithm, calculating the face normals for each adjacent triangle, summing them and normalizing. take data from `vertices` is easy because the indexing is always the same. the fact that method 1 works well proves that vertices are taken in the right way.... the issue is in method 2 normals calculation, but i can't figure it out. if you need more details, just tell me... thanks in advance

Comment: @fabian7 I think easiest way to (dis)prove is to render all summed sub-normals (into average) as a lines so you can see if there is not some of them flipped ... if they are just swap the cross product operands order for the sub normal in question... Without simple MCVE we can not test just guess ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

I was calculating the normals at the same time I was computing the zNoise.
So, it was possible that some vertices weren't at the right Z.

I solved calculating before all the Z, and then all the normals.
I just want to put some code:

```cpp
struct Triangle {
    glm::vec3 a, b, c;
};
```

```cpp
std::array<Triangle, 6> getAdjacentTriangles(glm::ivec2 pos) {
    int gap = 128;
    std::array<Triangle, 6> triangles;  
    triangles[0] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x - gap, pos.y),getVertex(pos.x - gap, pos.y + gap),
    };
    triangles[1] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x - gap, pos.y + gap), getVertex(pos.x, pos.y + gap)
    };
    triangles[2] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x, pos.y + gap), getVertex(pos.x + gap, pos.y)
    };
    triangles[3] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x + gap, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x + gap, pos.y - gap)
    };
    triangles[4] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x + gap, pos.y - gap),getVertex(pos.x, pos.y - gap),
    };
    triangles[5] = {
        getVertex(pos.x, pos.y), getVertex(pos.x, pos.y - gap), getVertex(pos.x - gap, pos.y)
    };
    return triangles;
}
```

```cpp
glm::vec3 calculateTriangleNormal(Triangle T) {
    glm::vec3 N = glm::cross(T.c - T.a, T.b - T.a);
    return N;
}
```

```cpp
void mapgen::updateNormals() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nVertices * 10; i += 10) {
        float xCoord = mapgen::MapVertices()[i];
        float yCoord = mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 1];
        glm::ivec2 pos = glm::ivec2(int(xCoord), int(yCoord));  
        if (pos.x > 128 && pos.x < 29952 - 128 && pos.y > 128 && pos.y < 19968 - 128) {

            std::array<Triangle, 6> adjacentTriangles = getAdjacentTriangles(pos);
            glm::vec3 sum(0.f);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                glm::vec3 normal = calculateTriangleNormal(adjacentTriangles[i]);
                sum += normal;
            }
            glm::vec3 N = glm::normalize(sum);

            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 6] = N.x;
            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 7] = N.y;
            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 8] = N.z;
        }
        else {
            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 6] = 0.f;
            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 7] = 0.f;
            mapgen::MapVertices()[i + 8] = 1.f;
        }
    }
}
```

Yaaaayy!