# Double precision in compute shader (full code)

Tags: opengl, glsl, double-precision

I send double precision data to my compute shader using an ssbo but somehow looses precision somewhere in the shader. I posted this problem [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/197454-Precision-loss-with-dvec3?p=1278888#post1278888) but has not yet received a response.

I read a position which contains 4 doubles that I use in calculations. If I in the beginning of the shader write the position to the buffer the values are correct. If I write to the buffer after my calculations I get a precision loss. I never change the values in the position. In my test I can even change "true" to "variable == variable" and loose precision only on that. Some of the code is shown in the post i linked to.

I had a similar problem with my constants which was solved with the LF suffix. Is there a similar fix for variables?

I have tried to isolate the problem, here is my code:

My .csh-file:

```
#version 430

struct aVec4 {
  double x, y, z, w;
};

struct FT {
  aVec4 force;
  aVec4 torque;
};

struct Triangle {
  aVec4 position;
  aVec4 normal;
  aVec4 depth;
};

layout( std430, binding = 0 ) buffer abc { Triangle bs[]; };
layout( std430, binding = 1 ) buffer def { FT forces[]; };
layout( local_size_x = 1 ) in;

dvec3 toVec3( in aVec4 vector ) {
  dvec3 v = dvec3( vector.x, vector.y, vector.z );
  return v;
}

aVec4 function1( inout Triangle triangles[2], inout int numTriangles ) {
  Triangle anotherTriangle = bs[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];
  int numBelow = 1;

  if ( anotherTriangle.depth.x < 0.0LF ) {
    numBelow++;
  }

  if ( numBelow == numBelow ) {
    numTriangles = 1;

    aVec4 result = anotherTriangle.position;
    return result;
  }
}

FT function2( in Triangle triangles[2], in int numTriangles ) {
  FT ft;
  dvec3 force = dvec3( 0.0LF, 0.0LF, 0.0LF );

  for ( int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++ ){
    dvec3 normal  = toVec3( triangles[i].normal );
    force  += - normal;
  }

  ft.force = triangles[0].position;
  return ft;
}

void main()
{
  Triangle triangles[2];
  triangles[0] = bs[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];
  int numTriangles = 1;

  aVec4 result = function1( triangles, numTriangles );
  FT ft = function2( triangles, numTriangles );
  ft.torque = result;

  forces[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = ft;
}
```

My .cpp-file:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <vector>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#include <cmath>

class Vec3
{
public:
  Vec3()
    : x(0)
    , y(0)
    , z(0)
    , w(0)
  {
  }

  Vec3(double x, double y, double z)
    : x(x)
    , y(y)
    , z(z)
    , w(0)
  {
  }

  double x, y, z, w;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vec3& v)
{
  stream << std::setprecision(20) << std::setw(20) << std::scientific;
  stream << "Vec3(" <<
    std::setw(23) << v.x << ", " <<
    std::setw(23) << v.y << ", " <<
    std::setw(23) << v.z << ") (" <<
    std::setw(23) << v.w << ")";
  return stream;
}


GLuint loadShader( std::string fileName )
{
  GLuint program = glCreateProgram( );
  GLuint shader = glCreateShader( GL_COMPUTE_SHADER );

  std::ifstream shaderStream(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::in );
  if (!shaderStream.is_open())
  {
    std::cout << "Could not open shader source file '" << fileName << "'." << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  std::string src;
  std::string line = "";
  while ( getline( shaderStream, line ) )
    src += "\n" + line;

  char const* srcPointer = src.c_str( );
  glShaderSource( shader, 1, &srcPointer, NULL );
  glCompileShader( shader );

  int rValue;
  glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &rValue );
  if (!rValue)
  {
    std::cout << "Unable to compile compute shader" << std::endl;
    GLchar log[ 10240 ];
    GLsizei length;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, 10239, &length, log );
    fprintf( stderr, "Compiler log:\n%s\n", log );
    exit( 40 );
  }

  glAttachShader(program, shader);
  glLinkProgram(program);

  glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &rValue );
  if (!rValue)
  {
    std::cout << "Unable to link compute shader program" << std::endl;
    GLchar log[ 10240 ];
    GLsizei length;
    glGetProgramInfoLog( program, 10239, &length, log );
    fprintf( stderr, "Linker log:\n%s\n", log );
    exit( 41 );
  }

  glDeleteShader( shader );

  return program;
}

struct ShaderData
{
  Vec3 position;
  Vec3 normal;
  Vec3 depth;
};



int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutCreateWindow( "TEST1" ); //TODO: Why?

  glewInit( );

  std::string shaderFileName = "tutorial_computeShaderBugSearch.csh";
  GLuint program = loadShader( shaderFileName );

  GLuint ssbo;
  GLuint result;

  glGenBuffers( 1, &ssbo );
  glGenBuffers( 1, &result );

  glUseProgram( program );

  std::vector< ShaderData > buf;
  buf.resize( 1 );

  ShaderData shaderData;
  shaderData.position = Vec3( double(1) / double(3), 0, 0 );
  shaderData.normal = Vec3( 1, 1, 1 );
  shaderData.depth.x = 1;
  buf[ 0 ] = shaderData;

  glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo );
  glBufferData( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buf.size( ) * sizeof(ShaderData), buf.data( ), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

  std::vector< Vec3 > forces;
  forces.resize( 2 ); // 1 for the forces + 1 for the torques

  glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, result );
  glBufferData( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, forces.size( ) * sizeof(Vec3), forces.data( ), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

  glUseProgram( program );
  glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo );
  glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, result );
  glDispatchCompute( 1, 1, 1 );
  glMemoryBarrier( GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT );

  glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, result );
  Vec3* ptr = (Vec3*)glMapBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY );

  Vec3 a = ptr[ 0 ];
  Vec3 b = ptr[ 1 ];

  std::cout << "a: " << std::setprecision(20) << a.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b: " << std::setprecision(20) << b.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "diff: " << std::abs(a.x-b.x) << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
a: 0.3333333432674408
b: 0.33333333333333331
diff: 9.9341074810688212e-099
```

Comment: I never used SSBO so this can be bogus but anyway current HW can not pass double interpolators from Vertex to Fragment shader they are truncated to floats instead or not compiled/linked at all...This is where I came across this issue [no 64bit interpolators in GLSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre: Considering this question is about compute shaders, I don't think that's a major concern.

Comment: Judging from the code you linked, the `Vertex` struct is misaligned. Try adding 3 scalar doubles after `depth` or a single dvec3 before it...

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Misalignment does not seem to be the problem in this case but I thank you for the input.