# Ray-tracing quartic surfaces

Tags: opengl, glsl, raytracing

I have implemented ray-tracing of quartic surfaces in GLSL

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 q; // Screen coordinates. Entire screen is covered by 2 triangles, in which the ray-tracing is done.

uniform vec3 X;  // Position of the screen centre in world coordinates.
uniform vec3 R;  // View direction in euler angles. 
uniform vec2 B;  // Screen width and height.

uniform vec3 P;  // Position of the eyes in the coordinates given by R.

out vec4 color;

const float pi = 2 * asin (1.0);

// Creating an unit vector from sferical coordinates.

vec3 sfe (const float fi, const float te)
{
    return vec3 (cos (fi) * cos (te), sin (fi) * cos (te), sin (te));
}

// Get the vector basis for view space.

mat3 getb (const vec3 r)
{
    mat3 M;

    M [0] = sfe (r [0], r [1]);

    vec3 a = sfe (r [0] + 0.5 * pi, 0);
    vec3 b = sfe (r [0], r [1] + 0.5 * pi);

    M [1] = a * cos (r [2]) + b * sin (r [2]);
    M [2] = - a * sin (r [2]) + b * cos (r [2]);

    return M;
}

// Get the pixel position in world coordinates.

vec3 getx (const vec3 e, const vec3 f, const vec2 b, const vec2 q)
{
    return b [0] * q [0] * e + b [1] * q [1] * f;
}

// Complex numbers.

// Complex multiplication.

vec2 nb (const vec2 a, const vec2 b)
{
   return vec2 (a [0] * b [0] - a [1] * b [1], a [0] * b [1] + a [1] * b 
[0]);
}

// Complex conjugate.

vec2 ks (const vec2 z)
{
    return vec2 (z [0], - z [1]);
}

// Complex division.

vec2 lm (const vec2 a, const vec2 b)
{
   return nb (a, ks (b)) / dot (b, b);
}

// Complex exponential.

vec2 ena (const vec2 z)
{
    return exp (z [0]) * vec2 (cos (z [1]), sin (z [1]));
}

// Complex logarithm.

vec2 ln (const vec2 z)
{
    float f;
    if (z [0] > 0)
        f = 0;
    else
        f = pi;
    return vec2 (0.5 * log (dot (z, z)), atan (z [1] / z [0]) + f);
}

// Complex power.

vec2 om (const float n, const vec2 z)
{
    if (z == vec2 (0, 0))
        return vec2 (0, 0);
    else
        return ena (n * ln (z));
}

// Ferrari's solution to quartic equation

// Solution to degree 2 equation.

vec2 [2] rov2 (const float a [3])
{
vec2 w [2];

float D = a [1] * a [1] - 4 * a [0] * a [2];

w [0] = (- vec2 (a [1], 0) - om (0.5, vec2 (D, 0))) / (2 * a [0]);
w [1] = (- vec2 (a [1], 0) + om (0.5, vec2 (D, 0))) / (2 * a [0]);

return w;
}

// Solution to degree 3 equation.

vec2 [3] rov3 (const float a [4])
{
vec2 w [3];

float p, q;

p = (3 * a [0] * a [2] - a [1] * a [1]) / (3 * a [0] * a [0]);
q = (2 * a [1] * a [1] * a [1] - 9 * a [0] * a [1] * a [2] + 27 * a [0] * a [0] * a [3]) / (27 * a [0] * a [0] * a [0]);

float A [3] = float [3] (1, q, - p * p * p / 27);

vec2 k [2] = rov2 (A);

vec2 u = om (1.0 / 3, k [0]);
vec2 U;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1)
{
    U = nb (u, ena (vec2 (0, i * 2 * pi / 3)));
    w [i] = U - p / 3 * lm (vec2 (1, 0), U) - vec2 (a [1], 0) / (3 * a [0]);;
}

return w;
}

// Solution to degree 4 equation.

vec2 [4] rov4 (const float a [5])
{
vec2 w [4];

float p, q, r;

p = (8 * a [2] * a [0] - 3 * a [1] * a [1]) / (8 * a [0] * a [0]);
q = (a [1] * a [1] * a [1] - 4 * a [2] * a [1] * a [0] + 8 * a [3] * a [0] * a [0]) / (8 * a [0] * a [0] * a [0]);
r = (- 3 * a [1] * a [1] * a [1] * a [1] + 256 * a [4] * a [0] * a [0] * a [0] - 64 * a [3] * a [1] * a [0] * a [0] + 16 * a [2] * a [1] * a [1] * a [0]) / (256 * a [0] * a [0] * a [0] * a [0]);

if (q == 0)
{
    float A [3] = float [3] (1, p, r);
    vec2 k [2] = rov2 (A);

    w [0] = om (0.5, k [0]);
    w [1] = - om (0.5, k [0]);
    w [2] = om (0.5, k [1]);
    w [3] = - om (0.5, k [1]);
}
else
{
    float B [4] = float [4] (8, 8 * p, 2 * p * p - 8 * r, - q * q);
    vec2 m [3] = rov3 (B);

    float o2 = sqrt (2.0f);

    vec2 omm = om (0.5, m [0]);

    vec2 om1 = om (0.5, - (2.0f * vec2 (p, 0) + 2.0f * m [0] - o2 * q * lm (vec2 (1, 0), omm)));
    vec2 om2 = om (0.5, - (2.0f * vec2 (p, 0) + 2.0f * m [0] + o2 * q * lm (vec2 (1, 0), omm)));

    w [0] = 0.5f * (- o2 * omm - om1) - vec2 (a [1], 0) / (4 * a [0]);
    w [1] = 0.5f * (- o2 * omm + om1) - vec2 (a [1], 0) / (4 * a [0]);
    w [2] = 0.5f * (+ o2 * omm - om2) - vec2 (a [1], 0) / (4 * a [0]);
    w [3] = 0.5f * (+ o2 * omm + om2) - vec2 (a [1], 0) / (4 * a [0]);
}

 return w;
}

// Evaluation and derivation of quartic.

struct quartic
{
bool lv [4];

float v4 [15];
float v3 [10];
float v2 [6];
float v1 [3];
float v0;

};

float eval (const quartic q, vec3 v)
{
float x = v [0];
float y = v [1];
float z = v [2];

float S = 0;

if (q.lv [0])
{
    S = S + x * x * (x * (q.v4 [0] * x + q.v4 [3] * y + q.v4 [4] * z) + y * (q.v4 [5] * z + q.v4 [12] * y)) +
               y * y * (y * (q.v4 [1] * y + q.v4 [6] * z + q.v4 [7] * x) + z * (q.v4 [8] * x + q.v4 [13] * z)) +
               z * z * (z * (q.v4 [2] * z + q.v4 [9] * x + q.v4 [10] * y) + x * (q.v4 [11] * y + q.v4 [14] * x));
}

if (q.lv [1])
{
    S = S + x * (x * (q.v3 [0] * x + q.v3 [3] * y + q.v3 [4] * z) - q.v3 [9] * y * z) +
               y * y * (q.v3 [1] * y + q.v3 [5] * z + q.v3 [6] * x) +
               z * z * (q.v3 [2] * z + q.v3 [7] * x + q.v3 [8] * y);
}

if (q.lv [2])
{
    S = S + x * (q.v2 [0] * x + q.v2 [3] * y) +
               y * (q.v2 [1] * y + q.v2 [4] * z) +
               z * (q.v2 [2] * z + q.v2 [5] * x);
}

if (q.lv [3])
    S = S + q.v1 [0] * x + q.v1 [1] * y + q.v1 [2] * z;

return S + q.v0;
}

quartic D (const quartic q0, const vec3 v)
{
quartic q;

q.lv = bool [4] (false, false, false, false);

if (q0.lv [0])
{
    q.lv [1] = true;

    q.v3 = float [10] (4 * q0.v4 [0] * v [0] + q0.v4 [3] * v [1] + q0.v4 [4] * v [2],
                            q0.v4 [7] * v [0] + 4 * q0.v4 [1] * v [1] + q0.v4 [6] * v [2],
                            q0.v4 [9] * v [0] + q0.v4 [10] * v [1] + 4 * q0.v4 [2] * v [2],
                            3 * q0.v4 [3] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v4 [12] * v [1] + q0.v4 [5] * v [2],
                            3 * q0.v4 [4] * v [0] + q0.v4 [5] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v4 [14] * v [2],
                            q0.v4 [8] * v [0] + 3 * q0.v4 [6] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v4 [13] * v [2],
                            2 * q0.v4 [12] * v [0] + 3 * q0.v4 [7] * v [1] + q0.v4 [8] * v [2],
                            2 * q0.v4 [14] * v [0] + q0.v4 [11] * v [1] + 3 * q0.v4 [9] * v [2],
                            q0.v4 [11] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v4 [13] * v [1] + 3 * q0.v4 [10] * v [2],
                            2 * q0.v4 [5] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v4 [8] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v4 [11] * v [2]);
}

if (q0.lv [1])
{
    q.lv [2] = true;

    q.v2 = float [6] (3 * q0.v3 [0] * v [0] + q0.v3 [3] * v [1] + q0.v3 [4] * v [2],
                           q0.v3 [6] * v [0] + 3 * q0.v3 [1] * v [1] + q0.v3 [5] * v [2],
                           q0.v3 [7] * v [0] + q0.v3 [8] * v [1] + 3 * q0.v3 [2] * v [2],
                           2 * q0.v3 [3] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v3 [6] * v [1] + q0.v3 [9] * v [2],
                           q0.v3 [9] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v3 [5] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v3 [8] * v [2],
                           2 * q0.v3 [4] * v [0] + q0.v3 [9] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v3 [7] * v[2]);
}

if (q0.lv [2])
{
    q.lv [3] = true;

    q.v1 = float [3] (2 * q0.v2 [0] * v [0] + q0.v2 [3] * v [1] + q0.v2 [5] * v [2],
                           q0.v2 [3] * v [0] + 2 * q0.v2 [1] * v [1] + q0.v2 [4] * v [2],
                           q0.v2 [5] * v [0] + q0.v2 [4] * v [1] + 2 * q0.v2 [2] * v [2]);
}

if (q0.lv [3])
    q.v0 = q0.v1 [0] * v [0] + q0.v1 [1] * v [1] + q0.v1 [2] * v [2];
else
    q.v0 = 0;

return q;
}

// Intersection with a ray.

struct ptn
{
vec3 x;
int l;
};

ptn pt (const vec3 x, const int l)
{
ptn p;

p.x = x;
p.l = l;

return p;
}

// Using Taylor series at screen point x0, we are trying to find intersection point in the form x0 + t * v.

ptn nika (const quartic q0, const vec3 x0, const vec3 v)
{
float k0 = eval (q0, x0);

quartic q = D (q0, v);
float k1 = eval (q, x0);

q = D (q, v);
float k2 = eval (q, x0);

q = D (q, v);
float k3 = eval (q, x0);

q = D (q, v);
float k4 = eval (q, x0);

vec2 k [4] = rov4 (float [5] (k4 / 24, k3 / 6, 0.5 * k2, k1, k0));

float t = 0;
int l = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
{
    if (abs (k [i] [1]) < 0.001 && k [i] [0] >= 0)
        if (k [i] [0] < t || l == 0)
        {
            t = k [i] [0];
            l = 1;
        }
}

return pt (x0 + t * v, l);
}

// Main loop.

void main()
{
mat3 b = getb (R);

vec3 x_ = transpose (b) * vec3 (0, B * q);

vec3 x = X + x_;
vec3 v = x_ - transpose (b) * P;

quartic q;

q.lv = bool [4] (true, false, true, false);

float r = 0.2;
float R = 1.25;

// A torus.

q.v4 = float [15] (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2);
q.v3 = float [10] (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
q.v2 = float [6] (- 2 * (R * R + r * r), - 2 * (R * R + r * r), 2 * (R * R - r * r), 0, 0, 0);
q.v1 = float [3] (0, 0, 0);
q.v0 = (R * R - r * r) * (R * R - r * r);

ptn p = nika (q, x, v);

vec3 svetlo = vec3 (1, 1, 1);

vec3 barva = vec3 (1, 0.5, 0.4);

color = vec4 (p.l * barva * svetlo, 1.0);
}
```

The algorithm provides mostly accurate results, hovewer, in some areas a visible noise appears.

[image: Image 1]

As the quartic (a torus) moves farther away from the screen, noise increases to the point that the torus becomes entirely obscured.

[image: Image 2]

I would like to know the cause of this noise and, if possible, how to eliminate it.

**[Edit by Spektre] dictionary**

- `barva` means color
- `svetlo` means light

Comment: It's really hard to read your code. I recommend you format it properly and use English names for identifiers, so everybody would understand. Also roughly explaining how you're doing that, or referencing a paper that you were basing your implementation on, might help.

Comment: I do not manage to read your code either. We published a while ago an article on ray tracing quadrics, it might help, it is here: http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?redirect=0&Paper=ISVC_torus@2007

Comment: you got a lot of floating operations on god know what intervals so the precision get lost ... see my struggle with [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) for some hints. You should estimate the intervals your variables operates in each stage to see if you are doing questionable FPU operations like adding small and big values etc ... also relative coordinates usually help (the lower the magnitude the better) which I bet is your problem as the problem increase with distance

Comment: I have added some explanation regarding how the program works. Also I didn't base my implementation on any paper - I merely used some basic knowledge about Ferrari's solution, complex numbers, quartic representation and its derivation, and Taylor series I learnt at school.

Comment: as I mentioned before read the linked answer in my previous comment and try the things I did there: 1. change `float,vec`  to `double,dvec` to see if there is difference. 2. use relative coordinates for the rays so move both ray start and torus as close together as you can so the abs(of coordinates) is as close to zero as it can. That can do a lot for computations like these. Also you are using `0,1,2 ...` as floating constants I got problems with that in the past I would feel much safe with `0.0,1.0,2.0...` Also I added dictionary to your question for those not understand Czech

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten the code to use double presission.

The scale-related noise was completely removed:

[image: Image 1]

However, scale-independent noise still persists:

[image: Image 2]

so it probably has different causes.

2-order surfaces are rendered without a single problem, while a similar noise curve appears when rendering 3-order surfaces, so it most likely has something to do with my solutions of 3- and 4-order equations.

Comment: Glad to see my advice helped (+1 btw). Still have you tried to translate both object and ray closer to zero (relative coordinates). Also you may have problem  near any singularity (multiplication result near zero or division by almost zero) as in higher orders you have usually more consequent multiplications making result more affected by low precision and aliasing/rounding//noise try to determine which parameters are at those black areas to determine which part of equation may be the problem.

Comment: Also try render your screen overlay primitive as wireframe without shader to see if the black areas are not just seem between triangles (hinting interpolators precision problem instead of the shader itself).