# Overlapping shadows in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, light

I've been modeling the Sun-Earth-Moon system to simulate the Aug. 21 eclipse. THREE.js is working fantastically.

The only hangup I have is with making shadows that overlap to create darker shadows in the joint area. I earlier [asked about creating umbras and penumbras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165893/three-js-casting-shadows-as-umbra-and-penumbra), but it turns out this requires making many, many directional lights, which is a performance killer. So I came up with a solution I think is rather clever: I'm creating various invisible, concentric Moons of different radii that cast shadows of different radii, centered on the same spot.

I already have an ambient light that tones down the opacity of one shadow. The trouble is that, if I have two objects individually casting their own shadows, one inside the other, they don't multiply. All I see is the biggest shadow.

Is there any way to make shadows multiply?

Comment: Could you possibly sketch what do you expect to happen? If an object is already occluded from a light (ie. inside a shadow) it wont be casting any other shadows.