# OpenGL GLSL Is precision affect the performance

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, precision

I had a problem in camera and objects movement which was not smooth and the scene looks like vibrating and I posted this question [Smooth movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566270/opengl-object-vibrate-after-moving-a-distance) then I make a linear interpolation for translation and spherical interpolation for quaternion but the problem is not solved, after 7 days I finally solved it, the solution was the precision,  in my shaders it was medium once I change it to high everything works fine, as I know the highp takes 12 bytes and the medium takes only 8 bytes so will this affect on the performance in case of **OpenGL ES**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `highp` can impact performance compared to `mediump`, both in terms of data size in memory and computational throughput.

Generally you need to use `highp` for vertex positions and texture coordinates, but can fall back to `mediump` for everything else. Don't globally use `highp` for everything - that's expensive.

Comment: how to make gl_FragCoord is highp without use global `precision highp float`

Comment: Use `#version 300 es` shaders (OpenGL ES 3.0), and it's `highp` by default.