# Ray tracing a Hemisphere

Tags: c, geometry, raytracing

I am currently working on a basic raytracing program using C, and i have managed to so some simple shapes **ex, sphere/box/plane/cone/...**, and i also did some shading to them using phong illumination.
But my question is that i can get a hang of how i can ray trace a Hemisphere , like is there a set equation that define the Hemisphere **if so enlighten me on it because i couldn't find any** , or is there a set method to do it that i couldn't figure out.

I have also tried to tried to cut the sphere with a plane and only show the only the top half but it didn't work (I am still new to all this so my understanding may be wrong).

Edit: Ok, I am sorry because i am really new to all this but here is what i have tryied.

```
#include "raytacing.h"

t_env  *init_sphere(t_env *e)
{
//sphere position and radius
    e->sph.posi.x = 0;
    e->sph.posi.y = 0;
    e->sph.posi.z = -1;
    e->sph.rad = 0;
    e->sph.color = (t_color){255, 255, 128);
    return (e);
}

t_env  *init_plane(t_env *e)
{
//plane position
    e->plane.posi.x = 0;
    e->olane.posi.y = -0.5;
    e->plane.posi.z = 0;
//plane normal
    e->plane.norm.x = 0;
    e->olane.norm.y = 1;
    e->plane.norm.z = 0;

    e->plane.color = (t_color){0, 255, 0);
    return (e);
}

double         inter_plane(t_env *e, double *t) //calculating plane intersection
{
    t_vect  dist;
    double  norm;

    norm = dot(e->plane.normal, e->r.direction);
    if (fabs(norm) > 1e-6)
    {
        dist = vect_sub(e->plane.posi, e->r.start);
        e->t0 = dot(dist, e->plane.normal) / norm;
        if (e->t0 < *t && e->t0 > 1e-6)
        {
            *t = e->t0;
            return (1);
        }
        else
            return (0);
    } 
    return (0);
}

double      inter_sph(t_env *e, double *t) //calculating sphere intersection
{
    double  delta;
    double  sqrtd;
    t_vect  dist;

    e->a = dot(e->r.direction, e->r.direction);
    dist = vect_sub(e->r.start, e->sph.posi);
    e->b = 2 * dot(dist, e->r.direction);
    e->c = dot(dist, dist) - e->sph.rad * e->sph.rad;
    delta = e->b * e->b - 4 * e->a * e->c;
    if (delta < 0)
        return (0);
    sqrtd = sqrt(delta);
    e->t0 = (-e->b + sqrtd) / (2 * e->a);
    e->t1 = (-e->b - sqrtd) / (2 * e->a);
    if (e->t0 > e->t1)
        e->t0 = e->t1;
    if ((e->t0 > 1e-6) && (e->t0 < *t))
    {
        *t = e->t0;
        return (1);
    }
    else
        return (0);
}

double      inter_hemisphere(t_env *e) //calculating hemisphere intersection
{
    t_vect  hit_normal;

    if (inter_sph(e, &e->t) == 1)
    {

        hit_normal = vect_add(e->r.start, vect_scalaire(e->t, e->r.direction));
        hit_normal = vect_normalize(hit_normal);

        if (inter_plane(e, &(e->t)) == 1)
        {
            if (dot(e->plane.normal, hit_normal) < 0)
                return (1);
            return (0);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

the `e->t` is . supposed to be the closest distance to the camera so that i get an exact display of close and far objects

And here i tried to apply what `Spektre` said and got some thing displayed and look like something like this:

[image: Result]

And when i try to rotate it i get this:

[image: Result]

Edit2 : After using `Spektre` Method I got a functional Intersection of a Hemisphere and the intersection look something like this.

```
double      inter_hemisphere(t_env *e, double *t)
{
    double  delta;
    double  sqrtd;
    t_vect  dist;

    e->a = dot(e->r.direction, e->r.direction);
    dist = vect_sub(e->r.start, e->sph.posi);
    e->b = 2 * dot(dist, e->r.direction);
    e->c = dot(dist, dist) - e->sph.rad * e->sph.rad;
    delta = e->b * e->b - 4 * e->a * e->c;
    if (delta < 0)
        return (0);
    sqrtd = sqrt(delta);
    e->t0 = (-e->b + sqrtd) / (2 * e->a);
    e->t1 = (-e->b - sqrtd) / (2 * e->a);
    t_vect  v2;

    v2 = vect_add(e->r.start, vect_sub(vect_scalaire(e->t0, e->r.direction), e->sph.posi));
    if (dot(e->plane.normal, v2) > 0.0)
        e->t0 =-1.0;
    v2 = vect_add(e->r.start, vect_sub(vect_scalaire(e->t1, e->r.direction), e->sph.posi));
    if (dot(e->plane.normal, v2) > 0.0)
        e->t1 =-1.0;
    if (e->t0 < 0.0)
        e->t0 = e->t1;
    if (e->t1 < 0.0)
        e->t1 = e->t0;
    double tt;
    tt = fmin(e->t0, e->t1);
    if (tt <= 0.0)
        tt = fmax(e->t0, e->t1);
    if (tt > 1e-6 && tt < e->t)
    {
        *t = tt;
        return (1);
    }  
    return (0);
}
```

And here is the Result:

[image: result]

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a helpful description. Show you attempt here please. Then expalin in which way it did not work.

Comment: cutting by plane is the way simply check the sign of `dot(plane_normal,hit_normal)` other option is to convert ray into object local coordinate system and just check the sign of one of the coordinates of hit position ...  No code, no MCVE no valid problem description makes this unanswerable so +Close

Comment: @Spektre i tried what you said and i got to be actually displayed but its still not correct and i cant seem to know where i am wrong . I did add what i tried to do with screenshots.

Comment: @HeartStabQQ You are testing only first hit on the sphere. In some cases you need to use the second one (if the first hit is on wrong side of the plane) that is why on fist image is missing the other side of the hemisphere. Your Rotation result hints you are not rotating properly ... btw rendering wire-frame of your objects (using vector graphics instead of ray-tracing) could help you debug (see if your ray-trace fits and if not exactly where...)

Comment: @HeartStabQQ I added answer with working code for the cutting by plane approach. However its based on mine GLSL ray tracer so you need to port it to yours (was too lazy to create workable raytracer from your code as it would be too much coding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to cut your sphere by a plane.

[image: overview]

If you have plane normal than any direction (point on sphere - sphere center) with the same direction to normal is cut off. Simply by this condition:

```
dot(point on sphere - sphere center , plane normal ) > 0.0
```

But do not forget to test both intersections of ray and sphere as the closest one can be on the other side of plane ...

I tried to implement this into mine GLSL Ray tracer:

- [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214)

And come up with this updated fragment shaders:

**Vertex (no change):**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
uniform float aspect;
uniform float focal_length;
uniform mat4x4 tm_eye;
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;

out smooth vec2 txt_pos;    // frag position on screen <-1,+1> for debug prints
out smooth vec3 ray_pos;    // ray start position
out smooth vec3 ray_dir;    // ray start direction
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    vec4 p;
    txt_pos=pos;
    // perspective projection
    p=tm_eye*vec4(pos.x/aspect,pos.y,0.0,1.0);
    ray_pos=p.xyz;
    p-=tm_eye*vec4(0.0,0.0,-focal_length,1.0);
    ray_dir=normalize(p.xyz);

    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fragment (added hemispheres):**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ray tracer ver: 1.000
//------------------------------------------------------------------
in smooth vec3      ray_pos;    // ray start position
in smooth vec3      ray_dir;    // ray start direction
uniform float       n0;         // refractive index of camera origin
uniform int         fac_siz;    // square texture x,y resolution size
uniform int         fac_num;    // number of valid floats in texture
uniform sampler2D   fac_txr;    // scene mesh data texture
out layout(location=0) vec4 frag_col;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define _reflect
#define _refract
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    const vec3  light_dir=normalize(vec3(0.1,0.1,1.0));
    const float light_iamb=0.1;                 // dot offset
    const float light_idir=0.5;                 // directional light amplitude
    const vec3 back_col=vec3(0.2,0.2,0.2);      // background color

    const float _zero=1e-6;         // to avoid intrsection with start point of ray
    const int _fac_triangles  =0;   // r,g,b,a, n, triangle   count, { x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 }
    const int _fac_spheres    =1;   // r,g,b,a, n, sphere     count, { x,y,z,r }
    const int _fac_hemispheres=2;   // r,g,b,a, n, hemisphere count,{ x,y,z,r,nx,ny,nz }
    // ray scene intersection
    struct _ray
        {
        dvec3 pos,dir,nor;
        vec3 col;
        float refl,refr;// reflection,refraction intensity coeficients
        float n0,n1;    // refaction index (start,end)
        double l;       // ray length
        int lvl,i0,i1;  // recursion level, reflect, refract
        };
    const int _lvls=4;
    const int _rays=(1<<_lvls)-1;
    _ray ray[_rays]; int rays;

    dvec3 v0,v1,v2,pos;
    vec3 c;
    float refr,refl,n1;
    double tt,t,a;
    int i0,ii,num,id;

    // fac texture access
    vec2 st; int i,j; float ds=1.0/float(fac_siz-1);
    #define fac_get texture(fac_txr,st).r; st.s+=ds; i++; j++; if (j==fac_siz) { j=0; st.s=0.0; st.t+=ds; }
    // enque start ray
    ray[0].pos=ray_pos;
    ray[0].dir=normalize(ray_dir);
    ray[0].nor=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    ray[0].refl=0.0;
    ray[0].refr=0.0;
    ray[0].n0=n0;
    ray[0].n1=1.0;
    ray[0].l =0.0;
    ray[0].lvl=0;
    ray[0].i0=-1;
    ray[0].i1=-1;
    rays=1;

    // loop all enqued rays
    for (i0=0;i0<rays;i0++)
        {
        // loop through all objects
        // find closest forward intersection between them and ray[i0]
        // strore it to ray[i0].(nor,col)
        // strore it to pos,n1
        t=tt=-1.0; ii=1; ray[i0].l=0.0;
        ray[i0].col=back_col;
        pos=ray[i0].pos; n1=n0;
        for (st=vec2(0.0,0.0),i=j=0;i<fac_num;)
            {
            c.r=fac_get;            // RGBA
            c.g=fac_get;
            c.b=fac_get;
            refl=fac_get;
            refr=fac_get;
            n1=fac_get;             // refraction index
            a=fac_get; id=int(a);   // object type
            a=fac_get; num=int(a);  // face count

            if (id==_fac_triangles)
             for (;num>0;num--)
                {
                v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get;
                v1.x=fac_get; v1.y=fac_get; v1.z=fac_get;
                v2.x=fac_get; v2.y=fac_get; v2.z=fac_get;
                dvec3 e1,e2,n,p,q,r;
                double t,u,v,det,idet;
                //compute ray triangle intersection
                e1=v1-v0;
                e2=v2-v0;
                // Calculate planes normal vector
                p=cross(ray[i0].dir,e2);
                det=dot(e1,p);
                // Ray is parallel to plane
                if (abs(det)<1e-8) continue;
                idet=1.0/det;
                r=ray[i0].pos-v0;
                u=dot(r,p)*idet;
                if ((u<0.0)||(u>1.0)) continue;
                q=cross(r,e1);
                v=dot(ray[i0].dir,q)*idet;
                if ((v<0.0)||(u+v>1.0)) continue;
                t=dot(e2,q)*idet;
                if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
                    {
                    ii=0; tt=t;
                    // store color,n ...
                    ray[i0].col=c;
                    ray[i0].refl=refl;
                    ray[i0].refr=refr;
                    // barycentric interpolate position
                    t=1.0-u-v;
                    pos=(v0*t)+(v1*u)+(v2*v);
                    // compute normal (store as dir for now)
                    e1=v1-v0;
                    e2=v2-v1;
                    ray[i0].nor=cross(e1,e2);
                    }
                }

            if (id==_fac_spheres)
             for (;num>0;num--)
                {
                float r;
                v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get; r=fac_get;
                // compute l0 length of ray(p0,dp) to intersection with sphere(v0,r)
                // where rr= r^-2
                double aa,bb,cc,dd,l0,l1,rr;
                dvec3 p0,dp;
                p0=ray[i0].pos-v0;  // set sphere center to (0,0,0)
                dp=ray[i0].dir;
                rr = 1.0/(r*r);
                aa=2.0*rr*dot(dp,dp);
                bb=2.0*rr*dot(p0,dp);
                cc=    rr*dot(p0,p0)-1.0;
                dd=((bb*bb)-(2.0*aa*cc));
                if (dd<0.0) continue;
                dd=sqrt(dd);
                l0=(-bb+dd)/aa;
                l1=(-bb-dd)/aa;
                if (l0<0.0) l0=l1;
                if (l1<0.0) l1=l0;
                t=min(l0,l1); if (t<=_zero) t=max(l0,l1);
                if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
                    {
                    ii=0; tt=t;
                    // store color,n ...
                    ray[i0].col=c;
                    ray[i0].refl=refl;
                    ray[i0].refr=refr;
                    // position,normal
                    pos=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*t);
                    ray[i0].nor=pos-v0;
                    }
                }
            if (id==_fac_hemispheres)
             for (;num>0;num--)
                {
                float r;
                v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get; r=fac_get;
                v1.x=fac_get; v1.y=fac_get; v1.z=fac_get;
                // compute l0 length of ray(p0,dp) to intersection with sphere(v0,r)
                // where rr= r^-2
                double aa,bb,cc,dd,l0,l1,rr;
                dvec3 p0,dp;
                p0=ray[i0].pos-v0;  // set sphere center to (0,0,0)
                dp=ray[i0].dir;
                rr = 1.0/(r*r);
                aa=2.0*rr*dot(dp,dp);
                bb=2.0*rr*dot(p0,dp);
                cc=    rr*dot(p0,p0)-1.0;
                dd=((bb*bb)-(2.0*aa*cc));
                if (dd<0.0) continue;
                dd=sqrt(dd);
                l0=(-bb+dd)/aa;
                l1=(-bb-dd)/aa;
                // test both hits-v0 against normal v1
                v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l0)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l0=-1.0;
                v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l1)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l1=-1.0;
                if (l0<0.0) l0=l1;
                if (l1<0.0) l1=l0;
                t=min(l0,l1); if (t<=_zero) t=max(l0,l1);
                if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
                    {
                    ii=0; tt=t;
                    // store color,n ...
                    ray[i0].col=c;
                    ray[i0].refl=refl;
                    ray[i0].refr=refr;
                    // position,normal
                    pos=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*t);
                    ray[i0].nor=pos-v0;
                    }
                }
            }
        ray[i0].l=tt;
        ray[i0].nor=normalize(ray[i0].nor);
        // split ray from pos and ray[i0].nor
        if ((ii==0)&&(ray[i0].lvl<_lvls-1))
            {
            t=dot(ray[i0].dir,ray[i0].nor);

            // reflect
            #ifdef _reflect
            if ((ray[i0].refl>_zero)&&(t<_zero))    // do not reflect inside objects
                {
                ray[i0].i0=rays;
                ray[rays]=ray[i0];
                ray[rays].lvl++;
                ray[rays].i0=-1;
                ray[rays].i1=-1;
                ray[rays].pos=pos;
                ray[rays].dir=ray[rays].dir-(2.0*t*ray[rays].nor);
                ray[rays].n0=ray[i0].n0;
                ray[rays].n1=ray[i0].n0;
                rays++;
                }
            #endif

            // refract
            #ifdef _refract
            if (ray[i0].refr>_zero)
                {
                ray[i0].i1=rays;
                ray[rays]=ray[i0];
                ray[rays].lvl++;
                ray[rays].i0=-1;
                ray[rays].i1=-1;
                ray[rays].pos=pos;

                t=dot(ray[i0].dir,ray[i0].nor);
                if (t>0.0)  // exit object
                    {
                    ray[rays].n0=ray[i0].n0;
                    ray[rays].n1=n0;
                    if (i0==0) ray[i0].n1=n1;
                    v0=-ray[i0].nor; t=-t;
                    }
                else{       // enter object
                    ray[rays].n0=n1;
                    ray[rays].n1=ray[i0].n0;
                    ray[i0  ].n1=n1;
                    v0=ray[i0].nor;
                    }
                n1=ray[i0].n0/ray[i0].n1;
                tt=1.0-(n1*n1*(1.0-t*t));
                if (tt>=0.0)
                    {
                    ray[rays].dir=(ray[i0].dir*n1)-(v0*((n1*t)+sqrt(tt)));
                    rays++;
                    }
                }
            #endif
            }
        else if (i0>0) // ignore last ray if nothing hit
            {
            ray[i0]=ray[rays-1];
            rays--; i0--;
            }
        }
    // back track ray intersections and compute output color col
    // lvl is sorted ascending so backtrack from end
    for (i0=rays-1;i0>=0;i0--)
        {
        // directional + ambient light
        t=abs(dot(ray[i0].nor,light_dir)*light_idir)+light_iamb;
        t*=1.0-ray[i0].refl-ray[i0].refr;
        ray[i0].col.rgb*=float(t);
        // reflect
        ii=ray[i0].i0;
        if (ii>=0) ray[i0].col.rgb+=ray[ii].col.rgb*ray[i0].refl;
        // refract
        ii=ray[i0].i1;
        if (ii>=0) ray[i0].col.rgb+=ray[ii].col.rgb*ray[i0].refr;
        }
    frag_col=vec4(ray[0].col,1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Vertex shader just creates the Ray position and direction which is interpolated by GPU and then Fragment shader handles each ray (per pixel).

I use this scene:

```cpp
// init mesh raytracer
ray.gl_init();
ray.beg();
//                 r   g   b rfl rfr   n
ray.add_material(1.0,0.7,0.1,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_hemisphere( 0.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
ray.add_material(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_box       ( 0.0, 0.0, 6.0,9.0,9.0,0.1);
ray.add_material(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.1,0.8,_n_glass); ray.add_sphere    ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,0.5);
ray.add_material(1.0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_sphere    (+2.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.5);
ray.add_material(0.1,1.0,0.1,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_box       (-2.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.5,0.5,0.5);
ray.add_material(0.1,0.1,1.0,0.3,0.0,_n_glass);
ray.add_tetrahedron
    (
     0.0, 0.0, 3.0,
    -1.0,-1.0, 4.0,
    +1.0,-1.0, 4.0,
     0.0,+1.0, 4.0
    );
ray.end();
```

containing single yellow hemisphere at `(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)` with radius `r=0.5` and plane normal `(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. Rotation of the object can by done simply by rotating the plane normal.

**And this is preview:**

[image: hemisphere]

As you can see hemisphere is working by just cutting with a plane ... The only important code from above for you is this (see the `***` comments):

```cpp
if (id==_fac_hemispheres) // *** ignore
 for (;num>0;num--) // *** ignore
    {
    float r;
    // *** here v0 is center, v1 is plane normal and r is radius
    v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get; r=fac_get;
    v1.x=fac_get; v1.y=fac_get; v1.z=fac_get;
    // *** this is ray/ellipsoid intersection returning l0,l1 ray distances for both hits
    // compute l0 length of ray(p0,dp) to intersection with sphere(v0,r)
    // where rr= r^-2
    double aa,bb,cc,dd,l0,l1,rr;
    dvec3 p0,dp;
    p0=ray[i0].pos-v0;  // set sphere center to (0,0,0)
    dp=ray[i0].dir;
    rr = 1.0/(r*r);
    aa=2.0*rr*dot(dp,dp);
    bb=2.0*rr*dot(p0,dp);
    cc=    rr*dot(p0,p0)-1.0;
    dd=((bb*bb)-(2.0*aa*cc));
    if (dd<0.0) continue;
    dd=sqrt(dd);
    l0=(-bb+dd)/aa;
    l1=(-bb-dd)/aa;
    // *** this thro away hits on wrong side of plane
    // test both hits-v0 against normal v1
    v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l0)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l0=-1.0;
    v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l1)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l1=-1.0;
    // *** this is just using closer valid hit
    if (l0<0.0) l0=l1;
    if (l1<0.0) l1=l0;
    t=min(l0,l1); if (t<=_zero) t=max(l0,l1);
    if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
        {
        ii=0; tt=t;
        // store color,n ...
        ray[i0].col=c;
        ray[i0].refl=refl;
        ray[i0].refr=refr;
        // position,normal
        pos=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*t);
        ray[i0].nor=pos-v0;
        }
    }
```

I used mine [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) as it returns both hits not just the first one.

If you cross check the spheres and hemispheres you will see I just added these two lines:

```cpp
v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l0)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l0=-1.0;
v2=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*l1)-v0; if (dot(v1,v2)>0.0) l1=-1.0;
```

which just converts ray distances to hit positions and computing the condition mentioned above...

Comment: Im sorry it took me a while to reply, but its working know, even tho at 1st when i tried to do your intersection i was having some NUL variables, But when i translated it to my way of doing the intersection it worked just fine and 1st try.

Comment: And about the rotation its working just fine either without even changing it, its just that what i did had the intersection calculation to be wrong. Thank you so much for your time. And i will update the code for the functional one so people in the future can see it.