# Atmosphere Scattering for Earth from space and on the ground

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Please provide prompt how to make the atmosphere of the Earth so that it is visible from space and from the ground (as shown in the image)

a model of the earth:

```
Earth = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(6700,32,32),ShaderMaterialEarth);
```

model of the cosmos:

```
 cosmos= new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(50000,32,32),ShaderMaterialCosmos);
```

and a light source:

```
sun = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
```

where to start, just I do not know. Perhaps this should do `ShaderMaterialCosmos`, where to pass position of the camera, and calculate how should be painted pixel. But how?

I tried using the following but get zero vectors at the entrance of the fragment shader
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html

```
vertexShader:

        #define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 
        const float ESun=1.0; 
        const float Kr = 0.0025; 
        const float Km = 0.0015; 
        const int nSamples = 2; 
        const float fSamples = 1.0; 

        const float fScaleDepth = 0.25; 

        varying vec2 vUv; 
        varying vec3 wPosition; 
        varying vec4 c0; 
        varying vec4 c1; 
        varying vec3 t0; 

         uniform vec3 v3CameraPos; ,    // The camera's current position
         uniform vec3 v3LightDir;       // Direction vector to the light source
         uniform vec3 v3InvWavelength;  // 1 / pow(wavelength, 4) for RGB
         uniform float fCameraHeight;    // The camera's current height

         const float fOuterRadius=6500.0;     // The outer (atmosphere) radius
         const float fInnerRadius=6371.0;      // The inner (planetary) radius

         const float fKrESun=Kr*ESun;           // Kr * ESun
         const float fKmESun=Km*ESun;           // Km * ESun
         const float fKr4PI=Kr*4.0*M_PI;            // Kr * 4 * PI
         const float fKm4PI=Km*4.0*M_PI;           // Km * 4 * PI

         const float fScale=1.0/(fOuterRadius-fInnerRadius);            // 1 / (fOuterRadius - fInnerRadius)
         const float fScaleOverScaleDepth= fScale / fScaleDepth;  // fScale / fScaleDepth

    const float fInvScaleDepth=1.0/0.25; 

    float getNearIntersection(vec3 v3Pos, vec3 v3Ray, float fDistance2, float fRadius2) 
{ 
   float B = 2.0 * dot(v3Pos, v3Ray); 
   float C = fDistance2 - fRadius2; 
   float fDet = max(0.0, B*B - 4.0 * C); 
   return 0.5 * (-B - sqrt(fDet)); 
} 

    float scale(float fCos) 
{ 
    float x = 1.0 - fCos; 
    return fScaleDepth * exp(-0.00287 + x*(0.459 + x*(3.83 + x*(-6.80 + x*5.25)))); 
} 


void main() { 


// Get the ray from the camera to the vertex and its length (which

  // is the far point of the ray passing through the atmosphere)

  vec3 v3Pos = position.xyz; 
  vec3 v3Ray = v3Pos - v3CameraPos; 
  float fFar = length(v3Ray); 

  v3Ray /= fFar; 



  // Calculate the closest intersection of the ray with

  // the outer atmosphere (point A in Figure 16-3)


  float fNear = getNearIntersection(v3CameraPos, v3Ray, fCameraHeight*fCameraHeight, fOuterRadius*fOuterRadius); 

  // Calculate the ray's start and end positions in the atmosphere,

  // then calculate its scattering offset

  vec3 v3Start = v3CameraPos + v3Ray * fNear; 

  fFar -= fNear; 
  float fStartAngle = dot(v3Ray, v3Start) / fOuterRadius; 
  float fStartDepth = exp(-fInvScaleDepth); 
  float fStartOffset = fStartDepth * scale(fStartAngle); 


  // Initialize the scattering loop variables


  float fSampleLength = fFar / fSamples; 
  float fScaledLength = fSampleLength * fScale; 
  vec3 v3SampleRay = v3Ray * fSampleLength; 
  vec3 v3SamplePoint = v3Start + v3SampleRay * 0.5; 



  // Now loop through the sample points

  vec3 v3FrontColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
  for(int i=0; i<nSamples; i++) { 

    float fHeight = length(v3SamplePoint); 
    float fDepth = exp(fScaleOverScaleDepth * (fInnerRadius - fHeight)); 
    float fLightAngle = dot(v3LightDir, v3SamplePoint) / fHeight; 
    float fCameraAngle = dot(v3Ray, v3SamplePoint) / fHeight; 
    float fScatter = (fStartOffset + fDepth * (scale(fLightAngle) * scale(fCameraAngle))); 
    vec3 v3Attenuate = exp(-fScatter *  (v3InvWavelength * fKr4PI + fKm4PI)); 
    v3FrontColor += v3Attenuate * (fDepth * fScaledLength); 
    v3SamplePoint += v3SampleRay; 

  } 


 wPosition = (modelMatrix * vec4(position,1.0)).xyz; 

  c0.rgb = v3FrontColor * (v3InvWavelength * fKrESun); 
  c1.rgb = v3FrontColor * fKmESun; 
  t0 = v3CameraPos - v3Pos; 

  vUv = uv; 

        }

fragmentShader: 

    float getMiePhase(float fCos, float fCos2, float g, float g2){ 

   return 1.5 * ((1.0 - g2) / (2.0 + g2)) * (1.0 + fCos2) / pow(1.0 + g2 - 2.0*g*fCos, 1.5);    
} 

// Rayleigh phase function
float getRayleighPhase(float fCos2){ 

   //return 0.75 + 0.75 * fCos2;
   return 0.75 * (2.0 + 0.5 * fCos2); 

} 


    varying vec2 vUv; 
    varying vec3 wPosition; 
    varying vec4 c0; 
    varying vec4 c1; 
    varying vec3 t0; 

      uniform vec3 v3LightDir; 
      uniform float g; 
      uniform float g2; 

    void main() { 

      float fCos = dot(v3LightDir, t0) / length(t0); 

    float fCos2 = fCos * fCos; 
    gl_FragColor = getRayleighPhase(fCos2) * c0 +  getMiePhase(fCos, fCos2, g, g2) * c1; 
    gl_FragColor = c1; 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: look at mine [Atmospheric scattering in GLSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) and also [n-body simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chapter 16](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html) of GPU Gem 2 has nice explanation and illustration for achieving your goal in real time.

Basically you need to perform ray casting through the atmosphere layer and evaluate the light scattering.

Comment: there is an example on glsl?

Comment: @NiSSaN. The example glsl code can be found here https://github.com/TPZF/GlobWeb/tree/master/shaders. Thumb up if you find it useful.

Comment: As I understand it correctly, have to switch between shaders when the camera is in space and on the ground?

Comment: Yes, they use different shaders to handle viewing from space and from ground.

Comment: Here is another related topics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162642/glsl-atmospheric-scattering-transformations-not-scaling-right

Comment: GPU Gems Chapter 16 link is dead! This one works in 2017: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html