# How to make an atmosphere using threejs

Tags: three.js, textures

I use three.js's `SphereGeometry` build an earth ,  and I want add a blue atmosphere to make it look better.
How can I do that?

Now the earth is looking like this

[image]

I want to render the atmosphere like below (just don't know how to render the light, maybe it called glow):

[image]

Comment: look at mine [Atmospheric scattering in GLSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) and also [n-body simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214) also this [Bump-map a sphere with a texture map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558700/2521214)

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom shader like this:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html

Or just use this ready made threex atmosphere-glow extension:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.geometricglow#threex.atmospherematerial.js

Result: http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.planets/examples/earth.html