# Bump-map a sphere with a texture map

Tags: graphics, textures, texture-mapping, bump-mapping

We would like to bump-map a sphere with a texture map. However, the surface
of the sphere has an area that is 10 times the area of the texture map(area for both in pixels). Describe different ways in which the texture map can be used for bump mapping.

Comment: Please be more specific. The areas of a texture and of a sphere cannot be compared because they have different units (texture is measured in pixels, sphere is measured in world area units).

Comment: ... which is not to mention the issue of projections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **usually rectangle texture is used for spheres**

   texture `(u,v)` coordinates are used as angles for spherical coordinates. The result is that texels are bigger near equator  and smaller near poles. At poles all the texels merge to single pixel. This is how to do it

   - [texturing spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804515/2521214)
   - [normal/bump mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214)

   When you use these maps (color,normal,light,clouds):

   [image: color]
   [image: normal]
   [image: light]
   [image: cloud]

   when combined with single light source (Sun) I got this result:

   [image: result]

   On the left side with [atmospheric scattering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) and on the right without it. If you zoom a bit you can see the mountains.
2. **There are more ways then just rectangular sphere maps**

   You can use non linear sphere maps with different properties like eqisurface/distance etc. Here some examples of sphere maps (from google):

   rectangular:

   [image: rectangular]

   equidistant/paper model:

   [image: equidistant/paper model]

   equidistant:

   [image: equidistant]