# GPU ray casting (single pass) with 3d textures in spherical coordinates

Tags: opengl, glsl, raycasting, polar-coordinates, volume-rendering

i' am implementing an algorithm of volume rendering "GPU ray casting single pass". For this, i used a float array of intensity values as 3d textures ( this 3d textures describes a regular 3d grid in spherical coordinates ).

Here there are example of array values:

```
   75.839354473071637,     
   64.083049468866022,    
   65.253933716444365,     
   79.992431196592577,     
   84.411485976957096,     
   0.0000000000000000,     
   82.020319431382831,     
   76.808403454586994,     
   79.974774618246158,     
   0.0000000000000000,     
   91.127273013466336,     
   84.009956557448433,     
   90.221356094672814,     
   87.567422484025627,     
   71.940263118478072,     
   0.0000000000000000,     
   0.0000000000000000,     
   74.487058398181944,
   ..................,
   ..................
```

(Here the complete data:[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lbXzRucUseF-ITzFgxqeLTd0WglJJOoz/view?usp=sharing))

the dimensions of spherical  grid are (r,theta,phi)=(384,15,768), and this is the input format for load textures:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, 384, 15, 768, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, dataArray)
```

And This is an image of my visualization:

[image]

The problem is that the visuization should be a disk, or at least a similar form.

i think that the problme is i do  not specify correctly the coordinates for textures( in spherical coordinates).

this is the vertex shader code:

```
  #version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vVertex; //object space vertex position

//uniform
 uniform mat4 MVP;   //combined modelview projection matrix

 smooth out vec3 vUV; //3D texture coordinates for texture lookup in   the fragment shader

void main()
{  
    //get the clipspace position 
     gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vVertex.xyz,1);

    //get the 3D texture coordinates by adding (0.5,0.5,0.5) to the object space 
    //vertex position. Since the unit cube is at origin (min: (-0.5,-0.5,-0.5) and max: (0.5,0.5,0.5))
    //adding (0.5,0.5,0.5) to the unit cube object space position gives us values from (0,0,0) to 
    //(1,1,1)
    vUV = vVertex + vec3(0.5);
}
```

and this is the fragmen shader code:

```
  #version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 vFragColor;   //fragment shader output

smooth in vec3 vUV;             //3D texture coordinates  form vertex shader 
                                 //interpolated by rasterizer

//uniforms
uniform sampler3D   volume;     //volume dataset
uniform vec3        camPos;     //camera position
uniform vec3        step_size;  //ray step size 




//constants
const int MAX_SAMPLES = 300;    //total samples for each ray march step
const vec3 texMin = vec3(0);    //minimum texture access coordinate
const vec3 texMax = vec3(1);    //maximum texture access coordinate





    vec4 colour_transfer(float intensity)
{

    vec3 high = vec3(100.0, 20.0, 10.0);
   // vec3 low = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   float alpha = (exp(intensity) - 1.0) / (exp(1.0) - 1.0);
   return vec4(intensity * high, alpha);

}



void main()
{ 
//get the 3D texture coordinates for lookup into the volume dataset
vec3 dataPos = vUV;


//Getting the ray marching direction:
//get the object space position by subracting 0.5 from the
//3D texture coordinates. Then subtraact it from camera position
//and normalize to get the ray marching direction
vec3 geomDir = normalize((vUV-vec3(0.5)) - camPos); 

//multiply the raymarching direction with the step size to get the
//sub-step size we need to take at each raymarching step
vec3 dirStep = geomDir * step_size; 

//flag to indicate if the raymarch loop should terminate
bool stop = false; 

//for all samples along the ray
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++) {
    // advance ray by dirstep
    dataPos = dataPos + dirStep;



    stop = dot(sign(dataPos-texMin),sign(texMax-dataPos)) < 3.0;

    //if the stopping condition is true we brek out of the ray marching loop
    if (stop) 
        break;
    // data fetching from the red channel of volume texture
    float sample = texture(volume, dataPos).r;  

     vec4 c = colour_transfer(sample);

    vFragColor.rgb = c.a * c.rgb + (1 - c.a) * vFragColor.a * vFragColor.rgb;
    vFragColor.a = c.a + (1 - c.a) * vFragColor.a;

    //early ray termination
    //if the currently composited colour alpha is already fully saturated
    //we terminated the loop
    if( vFragColor.a>0.99)
        break;
} 


}
```

How can i specific the coordinates for i will visualize the information in the 3d textures, in spherical cordinates?

UPDATE:

vertex shader :

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vVertex; //object space vertex position

//uniform
uniform mat4 MVP;   //combined modelview projection matrix

smooth out vec3 vUV; //3D texture coordinates for texture lookup in the             fragment shader



void main()
{  
    //get the clipspace position 
    gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vVertex.xyz,1);

     //get the 3D texture coordinates by adding (0.5,0.5,0.5) to the object     space 
    //vertex position. Since the unit cube is at origin (min: (-0.5,-   0.5,-0.5) and max: (0.5,0.5,0.5))
    //adding (0.5,0.5,0.5) to the unit cube object space position gives    us values from (0,0,0) to 
//(1,1,1)
vUV = vVertex + vec3(0.5);
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
#define Pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

layout(location = 0) out vec4 vFragColor;   //fragment shader output

smooth in vec3 vUV;             //3D texture coordinates form vertex shader 
                            //interpolated by rasterizer

//uniforms
uniform sampler3D   volume;     //volume dataset
uniform vec3        camPos;     //camera position
uniform vec3        step_size;  //ray step size 




//constants
const int MAX_SAMPLES = 200;    //total samples for each ray march step
const vec3 texMin = vec3(0);    //minimum texture access coordinate
const vec3 texMax = vec3(1);    //maximum texture access coordinate

// transfer function that asigned a color and alpha from sample    intensity
vec4 colour_transfer(float intensity)
{

    vec3 high = vec3(100.0, 20.0, 10.0);
    // vec3 low = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    float alpha = (exp(intensity) - 1.0) / (exp(1.0) - 1.0);

    return vec4(intensity * high, alpha);

}


// this function transform vector in spherical coordinates from cartesian
vec3 cart2Sphe(vec3 cart){
    vec3 sphe;
    sphe.x = sqrt(cart.x*cart.x+cart.y*cart.y+cart.z*cart.z);
    sphe.z = atan(cart.y/cart.x);
    sphe.y = atan(sqrt(cart.x*cart.x+cart.y*cart.y)/cart.z);
    return sphe;
}


void main()
{ 
    //get the 3D texture coordinates for lookup into the volume dataset
    vec3 dataPos = vUV;


    //Getting the ray marching direction:
    //get the object space position by subracting 0.5 from the
    //3D texture coordinates. Then subtraact it from camera position
    //and normalize to get the ray marching direction
    vec3 vec=(vUV-vec3(0.5)); 
    vec3 spheVec=cart2Sphe(vec); // transform position to spherical
    vec3 sphePos=cart2Sphe(camPos); //transform camPos to spherical
    vec3 geomDir= normalize(spheVec-sphePos); // ray direction


    //multiply the raymarching direction with the step size to get the
    //sub-step size we need to take at each raymarching step
    vec3 dirStep = geomDir * step_size ; 
    //flag to indicate if the raymarch loop should terminate

    //for all samples along the ray
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++) {
        // advance ray by dirstep
        dataPos = dataPos + dirStep;


        float sample;

        convert texture coordinates 
        vec3 spPos;
        spPos.x=dataPos.x/384;
        spPos.y=(dataPos.y+(Pi/2))/Pi;
        spPos.z=dataPos.z/(2*Pi);

        // get value from texture
         sample = texture(volume,dataPos).r;
         vec4 c = colour_transfer(sample)



        // alpha blending  function
         vFragColor.rgb = c.a * c.rgb + (1 - c.a) * vFragColor.a *      vFragColor.rgb;
        vFragColor.a = c.a + (1 - c.a) * vFragColor.a;


        if( vFragColor.a>1.0)
        break;
    } 

    // vFragColor.rgba = texture(volume,dataPos);
}
```

these are the point that generate a boundary cube:

```
 glm::vec3 vertices[8] = {glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f,   -0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
                                                 glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)};



    //unit cube indices
    GLushort cubeIndices[36] = {0, 5, 4,
                                                        5, 0, 1,
                                                        3, 7, 6,
                                                        3, 6, 2,
                                                        7, 4, 6,
                                                        6, 4, 5,
                                                        2, 1, 3,
                                                        3, 1, 0,
                                                        3, 0, 7,
                                                        7, 0, 4,
                                                        6, 5, 2,
                                                        2, 5, 1};
```

this is the visualization that it is generated:

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur1]

Comment: You need to convert your cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. How to do that depends on how your ball is positioned and sized.

Comment: I see some conflicts/inconsistencies in your text: volume rendering suggest object with volume either boundary representation or grid, polar coordinates are describing plane !!! and `(r,theta,phi)` suggest **spherical coordinates** ... so Which one the 3D texture is?  and what are the axises ... as if they where `r,theta,phi`  it would make no sense as the radius should be the value of cell not access axis... How are the data organized ?  How/what are you rendering a Quad covering screen or different stuff? what rays and casted from where how? deducing all from foreign not working code is hard

Comment: on second taught if the texture covers full volume not just surface then it could be `r,theta,phi` but still its not polar ... but that organization would have very varying  density of voxels per each `r` wasting a lot of memory. Once you realize what coordinate system you got then convert each ray potential hit position into target coordinates fetch texture and render ... so iterate ray in cartesian but fetch in "polar/cylindric/spherical/???". See [Curved Frosted Glass Shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33581643/2521214)

Comment: The coordinates are in spherical coordinates system, i going to edite this in my question

Comment: The 3d textures describe an object with disk form in spherical coordinates, my intention is visualize this disk within the boundary cube box , is it this possible?.

Comment: @sebastianpinto 1. to notify user `nick` you need to add `@nick` to your comment (works only for 1 user per comment which is present in current thread ). 2. yes it is possible will make an answer with some hints on how to achieve it (in comment it would be unreadable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what and how are you rendering. There are many techniques and configurations which can achieve them. I am usually using a single pass single quad render covering the screen/view while geometry/scene is passed as texture. As you have your object in a 3D texture then I think you should go this way too. This is how its done (Assuming perspective, uniform spherical voxel grid as a 3D texture):

1. **CPU side code**

   simply render single `QUAD` covering the scene/view. To make this more simple and precise I recommend you to use your sphere local coordinate system for camera matrix which is passed to the shaders (it will ease up the ray/sphere intersections computations a lot).
2. **Vertex**

   here you should cast/compute the ray position and direction for each vertex and pass it to the fragment so its interpolated for each pixel on the screen/view.

   So the camera is described by its position (focal point) and view direction (usually Z- axis in perspective **OpenGL**). The ray is casted from the focal point `(0,0,0)` in camera local coordinates into the `znear` plane `(x,y,-znear)` also in camera local coordinates. Where `x,y` is the pixel screen position wit aspect ratio corrections applied if screen/view is not a square.

   So you just convert these two points into sphere local coordinates (still Cartesian).

   The ray direction is just substraction of the two points...
3. **Fragment**

   first normalize ray direction passed from vertex (as due to interpolation it will not be unit vector). After that simply test ray/sphere intersection for each radius of the sphere voxel grid from outward to inward so test spheres from `rmax` to `rmax/n` where `rmax` is the max radius your 3D texture can have and `n` is ids resolution  for axis corresponding to radius `r`.

   On each hit convert the Cartesian intersection position to [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Convert them to texture coordinates `s,t,p` and fetch the Voxel intensity and apply it to the color (how depends on what and how are you rendering).

   So if your texture coordinates are `(r,theta,phi)`assuming `phi` is longitude and angles are normalized to `<-Pi,Pi>` and `<0,2*Pi>` and `rmax` is the max radius of the 3D texture then:

   ```
   s = r/rmax
   t = (theta+(Pi/2))/Pi
   p = phi/(2*PI)
   ```

   If your sphere is not transparent then stop on first hit with not empty Voxel intensity. Otherwise update ray start position and do this whole bullet again until ray goes out of the scene BBOX or no intersection occurs.

   You can also add Snell's law (add reflection refraction) by splitting ray on object boundary hits...

Here are some related **QA**s using this technique or having valid info that will help you achieve this:

- [GLSL atmospheric scattering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) this is almost the same as you should do.
- [ray and ellipsoid intersection accuracy improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470493/2521214) math for the intersections
- [Curved Frosted Glass Shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33581643/2521214) sub surface scattering
- [GLSL back raytrace through 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) reflections and refractions in geometry inside 2D texture
- [GLSL back raytrace through 3D volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) 3D Cartesian volume inside 3D texture

**[Edit1] example (after the input 3D texture was finally posted**

So when I put all the stuff above (and in comments) together I come up with this.

**CPU side code:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- GLSL Raytrace system ver: 1.000 ---------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _raytrace_spherical_volume_h
#define _raytrace_spherical_volume_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class SphericalVolume3D
    {
public:
    bool _init;         // has been initiated ?
    GLuint txrvol;      // SphericalVolume3D texture at GPU side
    int xs,ys,zs;

    float eye[16];      // direct camera matrix
    float aspect,focal_length;

    SphericalVolume3D()    { _init=false; txrvol=-1; xs=0; ys=0; zs=0; aspect=1.0; focal_length=1.0; }
    SphericalVolume3D(SphericalVolume3D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~SphericalVolume3D()   { gl_exit(); }
    SphericalVolume3D* operator = (const SphericalVolume3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //SphericalVolume3D* operator = (const SphericalVolume3D &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    // init/exit
    void gl_init();
    void gl_exit();

    // render
    void glsl_draw(GLint prog_id);
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SphericalVolume3D::gl_init()
    {
    if (_init) return; _init=true;
    // load 3D texture from file into CPU side memory
    int hnd,siz; BYTE *dat;
    hnd=FileOpen("Texture3D_F32.dat",fmOpenRead);
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    dat=new BYTE[siz];
        FileRead(hnd,dat,siz);
        FileClose(hnd);
    if (0)
        {
        int i,n=siz/sizeof(GLfloat);
        GLfloat *p=(GLfloat*)dat;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) p[i]=100.5;
        }

    // copy it to GPU as 3D texture
//  glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
//  glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
//  glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
    glGenTextures(1,&txrvol);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,txrvol);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
    xs=384;
    ys= 15;
    zs=768;
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, xs,ys,zs, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, dat);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    delete[] dat;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SphericalVolume3D::gl_exit()
    {
    if (!_init) return; _init=false;
    glDeleteTextures(1,&txrvol);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SphericalVolume3D::glsl_draw(GLint prog_id)
    {
    GLint ix;
    const int txru_vol=0;
    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    // uniforms
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"zoom"        ); glUniform1f(ix,1.0);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"aspect"      ); glUniform1f(ix,aspect);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"focal_length"); glUniform1f(ix,focal_length);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"vol_xs"      ); glUniform1i(ix,xs);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"vol_ys"      ); glUniform1i(ix,ys);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"vol_zs"      ); glUniform1i(ix,zs);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"vol_txr"     ); glUniform1i(ix,txru_vol);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"tm_eye"      ); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,eye);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+txru_vol);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,txrvol);

    // this should be a VAO/VBO
    glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
    glVertex2f(-1.0,+1.0);
    glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
    glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
    glEnd();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+txru_vol);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glUseProgram(0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

call init on app start when GL is already inited, exit before app exit while GL still works and draw when needed... The code is **C++/VCL** based so port to your environment (file access, strings, etc..) I also use the 3D texture in binary form as loading 85MByte ASCII file is a bit too much for my taste.

**Vertex:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
uniform float aspect;
uniform float focal_length;
uniform float zoom;
uniform mat4x4 tm_eye;
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;

out smooth vec3 ray_pos;    // ray start position
out smooth vec3 ray_dir;    // ray start direction
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    vec4 p;
    // perspective projection
    p=tm_eye*vec4(pos.x/(zoom*aspect),pos.y/zoom,0.0,1.0);
    ray_pos=p.xyz;
    p-=tm_eye*vec4(0.0,0.0,-focal_length,1.0);
    ray_dir=normalize(p.xyz);
    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

its more or less a copy from the volumetric ray tracer link.

**Fragment:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ray tracer ver: 1.000
//------------------------------------------------------------------
in smooth vec3      ray_pos;    // ray start position
in smooth vec3      ray_dir;    // ray start direction
uniform int         vol_xs,     // texture resolution
                    vol_ys,
                    vol_zs;
uniform sampler3D   vol_txr;    // scene mesh data texture
out layout(location=0) vec4 frag_col;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// compute length of ray(p0,dp) to intersection with ellipsoid((0,0,0),r) -> view_depth_l0,1
// where r.x is elipsoid rx^-2, r.y = ry^-2 and r.z=rz^-2
float view_depth_l0=-1.0,view_depth_l1=-1.0;
bool _view_depth(vec3 _p0,vec3 _dp,vec3 _r)
    {
    double a,b,c,d,l0,l1;
    dvec3 p0,dp,r;
    p0=dvec3(_p0);
    dp=dvec3(_dp);
    r =dvec3(_r );
    view_depth_l0=-1.0;
    view_depth_l1=-1.0;
    a=(dp.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(dp.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(dp.z*dp.z*r.z); a*=2.0;
    b=(p0.x*dp.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*dp.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*dp.z*r.z); b*=2.0;
    c=(p0.x*p0.x*r.x)
     +(p0.y*p0.y*r.y)
     +(p0.z*p0.z*r.z)-1.0;
    d=((b*b)-(2.0*a*c));
    if (d<0.0) return false;
    d=sqrt(d);
    l0=(-b+d)/a;
    l1=(-b-d)/a;
    if (abs(l0)>abs(l1)) { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0)          { a=l0; l0=l1; l1=a; }
    if (l0<0.0) return false;
    view_depth_l0=float(l0);
    view_depth_l1=float(l1);
    return true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const float pi =3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
const float pi2=6.2831853071795864769252867665590;
float atanxy(float x,float y) // atan2 return < 0 , 2.0*M_PI >
        {
        int sx,sy;
        float a;
        const float _zero=1.0e-30;
        sx=0; if (x<-_zero) sx=-1; if (x>+_zero) sx=+1;
        sy=0; if (y<-_zero) sy=-1; if (y>+_zero) sy=+1;
        if ((sy==0)&&(sx==0)) return 0;
        if ((sx==0)&&(sy> 0)) return 0.5*pi;
        if ((sx==0)&&(sy< 0)) return 1.5*pi;
        if ((sy==0)&&(sx> 0)) return 0;
        if ((sy==0)&&(sx< 0)) return pi;
        a=y/x; if (a<0) a=-a;
        a=atan(a);
        if ((x>0)&&(y>0)) a=a;
        if ((x<0)&&(y>0)) a=pi-a;
        if ((x<0)&&(y<0)) a=pi+a;
        if ((x>0)&&(y<0)) a=pi2-a;
        return a;
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    float a,b,r,_rr,c;
    const float dr=1.0/float(vol_ys);       // r step
    const float saturation=1000.0;          // color saturation voxel value
    vec3  rr,p=ray_pos,dp=normalize(ray_dir);
    for (c=0.0,r=1.0;r>1e-10;r-=dr)         // check all radiuses inwards
        {
        _rr=1.0/(r*r); rr=vec3(_rr,_rr,_rr);
        if (_view_depth(p,dp,rr))           // if ray hits sphere
            {
            p+=view_depth_l0*dp;            // shift ray start position to the hit
            a=atanxy(p.x,p.y);              // comvert to spherical a,b,r
            b=asin(p.z/r);
            if (a<0.0) a+=pi2;              // correct ranges...
            b+=0.5*pi;
            a/=pi2;
            b/=pi;
            // here do your stuff
            c=texture(vol_txr,vec3(b,r,a)).r;// fetch voxel
            if (c>saturation){ c=saturation; break; }
            break;
            }
        }
    c/=saturation;

    frag_col=vec4(c,c,c,1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

its a slight modification of the volumetric ray tracer link.

**Beware that I assume that the axises inside the texture are:**

```
latitude,r,longitude
```

implied by the resolutions (longitude should be double resolution of the latitude) so if it does not match your data just reorder the axises in fragment ... I have no clue what the values of the Voxel cell mean so I sum them like intensity/density for the final color and once saturation sum reached stop the raytrace but instead you should your computation stuff you intend.

**Here preview:**

[image: preview]

I used this camera matrix `eye` for it:

```
// globals
SphericalVolume3D vol;
// init (GL must be already working)
vol.gl_init();

// render
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-2.5);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,vol.eye);
vol.glsl_draw(prog_id);

glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hdc);

// exit (GL must be still working)
vol.gl_init();
```

The ray/sphere hit is working properly, also the hit position in spherical coordinates are working as should so the only thing left is the axis order and color arithmetics ...

Comment: thanks so much, i going test this solución to see if ir work

Comment: i tried to follow the steps, but this no work very well. i going to update my post with the new result applying your steps in vertex and fragment shader.
There are something incorret in my code?.

In Cpu part i rendered a boundarie box and load 3d textures, also i define  "camPos" and  "step size" that i pase for uniform variable to shaders.

in Fragmen shader i calculate the ray direction.

Comment: @sebastianpinto 1. on CPU side you should render just a single planar QUAD covering screen (4 x 2D vertexes all combinations of +/-1) not a 3D box !!!.  2. On vertex you are not computing ray direction at all the vUV makes no sense you can not compute texture coordinate in vertex (unless I am missing something) 3. fragment: use `atan2` for longitude angle computation not `atan`  and make sure the angles are in correct ranges especially latitude, I do not see any ray/sphere intersection code. 4. you still did not share the 3D input texture so no one can try to code this ...

Comment: @sebastianpinto in case you do not have `atan2(y,x)` (not sure if it is implemented in GLSL or not) then you can use mine [atanxy(x,y)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697187/2521214) instead ... its the same just the operands are swapped.

Comment: this file contain the volume datasets, the format for load this to texture buffer is : glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, 384, 15, 768, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, volumeData).[volumeData] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lbXzRucUseF-ITzFgxqeLTd0WglJJOoz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @sebastianpinto see [edit1] ... you should also put the 3D texture link into your question ... there are some debug dead code left in the source however so ignore it ... (you know the `if(0)` and commented out stuff)

Comment: hi spektra, sorry for bother again, but i don't cannot execute the code. Could you send me the full code ?. I think that the problem is my dependencies.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @sebastianpinto hi. The only things missing from my code is the Window stuff (like creating GL context, registering extentions etc like GLEW) and loading/compiling/linking the shaders (which you should already have as otherwise you would not have any output image) anyway all of that you can find in here: [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214). I can post a small demo but I am using Borland/Embarcadero IDE which means you would not be able to compile it in MSVC++ or any other IDE without porting anyway so I do not see any point.

Comment: @sebastianpinto Also **do not forget to pass correct `prog_id`** to the class draw function it should be the ID of the compiled/linked shader. The only stuff I used for this was `gl_simple.h` from the link in previous comment, `GLEW.h` and `GLEW.c` (no DLL nor OBJ) but I got some old version newer ones might be initialized differently haven't updated it for years and GL,GLEXT,WGL headers for the Win32/OpenGL). Also I do mix old and new apis so if you have GL core context you need to rewrite the QUAD into VBO/VAO. GLSL core context is OK...

Comment: I understand,i was compiling and running the code for console in linux. I going to  fix the code for my enviroment.