# Creating gyroid pattern in 2D image algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to fill an image with [gyroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroid) lines with certain thickness at certain spacing, but math is not my area. I was able to create a sine wave and shift a bit in the X direction to make it looks like a gyroid but it's not the same.

The idea behind is to stack some images with the same resolution and replicate gyroid into 2D images, so we still have XYZ, where Z can be 0.01mm to 0.1mm per layer

What i've tried:

```
int sineHeight = 100;
int sineWidth = 100;
int spacing = 100;
int radius = 10;

for (int y1 = 0; y1 < mat.Height; y1 += sineHeight+spacing)
for (int x = 0; x < mat.Width; x++)
{
    // Simulating first image
    int y2 = (int)(Math.Sin((double)x / sineWidth) * sineHeight / 2.0 + sineHeight / 2.0 + radius);
    Circle(mat, new System.Drawing.Point(x, y1+y2), radius, EmguExtensions.WhiteColor, -1, LineType.AntiAlias);

    // Simulating second image, shift by x to make it look a bit more with gyroid
    y2 = (int)(Math.Sin((double)x / sineWidth + sineWidth) * sineHeight / 2.0 + sineHeight / 2.0 + radius);
    Circle(mat, new System.Drawing.Point(x, y1 + y2), radius, EmguExtensions.GreyColor, -1, LineType.AntiAlias);
}
```

Resulting in: (White represents layer 1 while grey layer 2)
[image: result]

Still, this looks nothing like real [gyroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroid), how can I replicate the formula to work in this space? [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have just single ugly slice because I do not see any `z` in your code (its correct the surface has horizontal and vertical sin waves like this every `0.5*pi` in `z`).

To see the 3D surface you have to raycast `z` ...

I would expect some conditional testing of actually iterated `x,y,z` result of **gyroid** equation against some small non zero number like `if (result<= 1e-6)` and draw the stuff only then or compute color from the result instead. This is ideal to do in GLSL.

In case you are not familiar with GLSL and shaders the Fragment shader is executed for each pixel (called fragment) of the rendered QUAD so you just put the code inside your nested `x,y` for loops and use your `x,y` instead of `pos` (you can ignore the Vertex shader its not important).

You got 2 basic options to render this:

**Blending the ray casted surface pixels together** creating **X-Ray** like image. It can be combined with [SSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33581643/2521214) techniques to get the impression of glass or semitransparent material. Here simple GLSL example for the blending:

**Vertex:**

```cpp
#version 400 core

in vec2 position;
out vec2 pos;

void main(void)
    {
    pos=position;
    gl_Position = vec4(position.xy,0.0,1.0);
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
#version 400 core

in vec2 pos;
out vec3 out_col;

void main(void)
    {
    float n,x,y,z,dz,d,i,di;
    const float scale=2.0*3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    n=100.0;                        // layers
    x=pos.x*scale;                  // x postion of pixel
    y=pos.y*scale;                  // y postion of pixel
    dz=2.0*scale/n;                 // z step
    di=1.0/n;                       // color increment
    i=0.0;                          // color intensity
    for (z=-scale;z<=scale;z+=dz)   // do all layers
        {
        d =sin(x)*cos(y);           // compute gyroid equation
        d+=sin(y)*cos(z);
        d+=sin(z)*cos(x);
        if (d<=1e-6) i+=di;         // if near surface add to color
        }
    out_col=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)*i;
    }
```

Usage is simple just render 2D quad covering screen without any matrices with corner `pos` points in range `<-1,+1>`. Here result:

[image: preview 3D blend]

Another technique is to render first hit to surface creating **mesh** like image. In order to see the details we need to add basic (double sided) directional lighting for which surface normal is needed. The normal can be computed by simply partialy derivate the equation by `x,y,z`. As now the surface is opaque then we can stop on first hit and also ray cast just single period in `z` as anything after that is hidden anyway. Here simple example:

**Fragment:**

```cpp
#version 400 core

in vec2 pos;                        // input fragmen (pixel) position <-1,+1>
out vec3 col;                       // output fragment (pixel) RGB color <0,1>

void main(void)
    {
    bool _discard=true;
    float N,x,y,z,dz,d,i;
    vec3 n,l;
    const float pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    const float scale =3.0*pi;      // 3.0 periods in x,y
    const float scalez=2.0*pi;      // 1.0 period in z
    N=200.0;                        // layers per z (quality)
    x=pos.x*scale;                  // <-1,+1> -> [rad]
    y=pos.y*scale;                  // <-1,+1> -> [rad]
    dz=2.0*scalez/N;                // z step
    l=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);            // light unit direction
    i=0.0;                          // starting color intensity
    n=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);            // starting normal only to get rid o warning
    for (z=0.0;z>=-scalez;z-=dz)    // raycast z through all layers in view direction
        {
        // gyroid equation
        d =sin(x)*cos(y);           // compute gyroid equation
        d+=sin(y)*cos(z);
        d+=sin(z)*cos(x);
        // surface hit test
        if (d>1e-6) continue;       // skip if too far from surface
        _discard=false;             // remember that surface was hit
        // compute normal
        n.x =+cos(x)*cos(y);        // partial derivate by x
        n.x+=+sin(y)*cos(z);
        n.x+=-sin(z)*sin(x);
        n.y =-sin(x)*sin(y);        // partial derivate by y
        n.y+=+cos(y)*cos(z);
        n.y+=+sin(z)*cos(x);
        n.z =+sin(x)*cos(y);        // partial derivate by z
        n.z+=-sin(y)*sin(z);
        n.z+=+cos(z)*cos(x);
        break;                      // stop raycasting
        }
    // skip rendering if no hit with surface (hole)
    if (_discard) discard;
    // directional lighting
    n=normalize(n);
    i=abs(dot(l,n));
    // ambient + directional lighting
    i=0.3+(0.7*i);
    // output fragment (render pixel)
    gl_FragDepth=z;                 // depth (optional)
    col=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)*i;        // color
    }
```

I hope I did not make error in partial derivates. Here result:

[image: preview 3D surface]

**[Edit1]**

Based on your code I see it like this (X-Ray like Blending)

```cpp
var mat = EmguExtensions.InitMat(new System.Drawing.Size(2000, 1080));
double zz, dz, d, i, di = 0;
const double scalex = 2.0 * Math.PI / mat.Width;
const double scaley = 2.0 * Math.PI / mat.Height;
const double scalez = 2.0 * Math.PI;
uint layerCount = 100;            // layers
for (int y = 0; y < mat.Height; y++)
    {
        double yy = y * scaley; // y position of pixel
        for (int x = 0; x < mat.Width; x++)
            {
            double xx = x * scalex; // x position of pixel                
            dz = 2.0 * scalez / layerCount; // z step
            di = 1.0 / layerCount; // color increment
            i = 0.0; // color intensity
            for (zz = -scalez; zz <= scalez; zz += dz) // do all layers
        {
        d =  Math.Sin(xx) * Math.Cos(yy); // compute gyroid equation
        d += Math.Sin(yy) * Math.Cos(zz);
        d += Math.Sin(zz) * Math.Cos(xx);
        if (d > 1e-6) continue;
        i += di; // if near surface add to color
        }
    i*=255.0;
    mat.SetByte(x, y, (byte)(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243535/discussion-on-answer-by-spektre-creating-gyroid-pattern-in-2d-image-algorithm).