# Atmospheric light scattering implementation

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shader, light-scattering

I'm trying to implement an atmospheric scattering in openGL. I'm using this "paper" as tutorial: 
http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GDC_02_HoffmanPreetham.pdf

However I have some difficulties to understand certain points and to figure out some constants.

Basically I've to implement these formulas: 
[image]

Firstly i don't know if s is the distance from eye to the dome or the distance from eye to the light source (here sun) position.
Same for the angle theta I can't figure out if it's the angle from ground to sun or to the dome position the eye is looking at.

Secondly in this slide:
[image]
It tells me the blue color of the sky will appears. I know it's cause of rayleigh scattering but there is something i can't understand. All the calculation in the formulas above give me a scalar: so how a white light of the sun wich is basically a vec3(1,1,1), will become blue when I multiply it by scalars, it will only get in gray scale because I will have for result for example vec3(0.8,0.8,0.8). I mean , if some different sky color appears, I must multiply the sun light with a vec3 to change the RGB value differently.

Now I encountered some difficulties to implement my shader.
Here is the code for the sky shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 vpoint;

in vec2 vtexcoord;


out vec2 uv;


out vec3 atmos;


uniform mat4 M;

uniform mat4 V;

uniform mat4 P;


mat4 MVP = P*V*M;



//uniform vec3 lpos;

vec3 lpos = vec3(100,0,0);

uniform vec3 cpos;



vec3 br = vec3(5.5e-6, 13.0e-6, 22.4e-6);

vec3 bm = vec3(21e-6);





float g = -0.75f;


vec3 Esun = vec3(2000,2000,2000);




vec3 Br(float theta){
return 3/(16*3.14) * br * (1+cos(theta)*cos(theta));

}


vec3 Bm(float theta){
return 1/(4*3.14) * bm * ((1 - g)*(1 - g))/(pow(1+g*g-
2*g*cos(theta),3/2));

}


vec3 atmospheric(float theta, float s){
return (Br(theta)*Bm(theta))/(br+bm) * Esun * (1- exp( -(br+bm)*s ));

}


void main() {

gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vpoint, 1.0);
uv = vtexcoord;

vec3 domePos = vec3(M*vec4(vpoint,1.0));

vec3 ldir = lpos - domePos;

float s = length(domePos-cpos);
float theta = acos(dot(normalize(ldir-domePos),normalize(domePos-
cpos)*vec3(1,1,0)));

atmos = atmospheric(theta,s)*1000000*5;

}
```

I don't get what I'm expected, here is what I get:

[image]

I only have the blue, and no redish sunset, yet the sun is low and according to the different tutorials I have seen, i should see some redish color appear when the sun goes low.

Comment: "*white light of the sun*" The sun does not give off white light.

Comment: @JimZer just a bet (too lazy to analyze your code) near sun your illumination is oversaturated (much higher then the image color depth) so it got truncated to white. You should truncate all the channels as single vector and not per channel. Also take a look at my scattering http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214 it is a bit simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning** I'm not an expert on this field, take this with a grain of salt.

[image: s and Theta meanings]
*This pretty much says it all.*

*s* is the distance between the vertex/pixel and the camera.
*θ* is the angle between the sun and the line of sight.

In order to compute θ you need to know the "yellow line" and the "line of sight".
The latter is ordinary shader math; the former is just a way to express how high on the sky the sun is. You can model it as a ray from the sun to a point on the ground.

---

All the formula above gives you vectors.
*L<sub>0</sub>* is a vector.
*E<sub>sun</sub>* is also a vector.

The slides basically says that the physic concepts like *Radiance* and *Irradiance* (E<sub>sun</sub>) are continuous on the spectrum and one should use a *Spectral Power Distribution* to describe lights and colors.
A faster approach however is to do the math only on three points of the spectrum, the one for the R, G and B wavelengths.
In practice this says that *E<sub>sun</sub>* is a vector describing the irradiance of the sun for the three RGB wavelength.

The blue of the sky comes from the parameter β<sub>R</sub> which depends on *θ* which depends on the "line of sight" which depends on the altitude of the fragment of the sky being coloured.

Comment: Nice , I could much better understand.
However I only have the blue, and no redish sunset, yet the sun is low and according to the different tutorials I have seen, i should see some redish color appear when the sun goes low.
I update my post with what iI can get:
Have you any ideas ?