# GLSL Fresnel effect makes half of my sphere white

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, react-three-fiber, fresnel

Here in app using r3f, in my sphere object I use the fresnel effect in my vertex shader, but the problem is that when the sphere is rotated the other side is pure white like in the example bellow ↓
[image: The bug]

Here is my code:

Vertex.glsl:
(cnoise funciton taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/670c22f3966e662d2f83))

```
uniform float uTime;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying float vDisplacement;

// cnoise function...

void main() {
  vPosition = position;
  vNormal = normal;
  vUv = uv;

  float customSpeed = uTime;
  customSpeed = customSpeed * 1.15;

  vec3 animatedNormal = normal;
  animatedNormal = animatedNormal * 2.;
  animatedNormal.x += customSpeed / 2.5;
  animatedNormal.y += customSpeed / 3.;
  animatedNormal.z += customSpeed / 4.;

  vDisplacement = cnoise2(vec4(animatedNormal, 1.), vec4(10.)) / 7.;

  vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vDisplacement;
  vec4 modelViewMatrixPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
  vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrixPosition;
  gl_Position = projectedPosition;
}
```

Fragment.glsl:

```
uniform sampler2D uSky;

varying float vDisplacement;

varying highp vec3 vPosition;
varying highp vec3 vNormal;

#define PI 3.14159265359

void main() {
  float phi = acos(vNormal.y);

  float angle = atan(vNormal.x, vNormal.z);

  vec2 fakeUv = vec2((angle + PI) / (2. * PI), phi / PI);

  float fresnel = dot(normalize(cameraPosition - vPosition), normalize(vNormal));
  vec4 texture = texture2D(uSky, fakeUv / 3. + vDisplacement);

  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vec3(1.), texture.rgb, fresnel * 1.2), 1.0);
  // gl_FragColor = texture; // if we only use this it works fine

}
```

Sphere.tsx:

```
// the jsx for the sphere
      <mesh ref={ref}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[2, 200]} />
        <shaderMaterial
          ref={shaderMaterialRef}
          vertexShader={vertex}
          fragmentShader={fragment}
        />
      </mesh>

// how I am rotating it
      useFrame(() => {
          ref.current.rotation.y = 30;
      }, [])
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: looks like double sided normal problem try `float fresnel = abs(dot(normalize(cameraPosition - vPosition), normalize(vNormal)));` if it makes any difference

Comment: @Spektre It gives me this result now: [link](https://imgur.com/a/IzJFOLx)

Comment: ok so its a part of the problem ... what is the desired output (spot light perhaps)? the result suggest your `vNormal` is not computed correctly or its not in the same coordinate system as `cameraPosition` and or `vPosition` all 3 vectors must be in the same one

Comment: Desired output is something like this, (only the white edges): [Image link](https://imgur.com/a/dOl4oDZ), the vNormal, vPosition and camera position are the default variables three js provides.

Comment: ahh ... the effect is aligned to camera (no matter how you rotate object or move camera it stays the same) or light (your current state)?  if the first then your have to use camera local coordinate system and float `fresnel = abs(dot(normalize(vPosition), normalize(vNormal)));`  to transform to camera local you have to have your camera matrix see [How do I compose a rotation matrix with human readable angles from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) btw. if you use this to fake atmosphere take a loo at my [Atmospheric scattering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214)